# How many off-topic comments does this have?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question, locked-posts

I went to up-vote a comment on the question [Offensive, inappropriate, and un-professional chat room names](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255221/offensive-inappropriate-and-un-professional-chat-room-names).

But I found that it was locked.

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

I see four comments, one of them by the moderator that locked it. Of the three others, I can't figure out which ones are off-topic, but apparently there is a "high amount".

Possible guesses:

1. In contrast to my opinion, the three comments are off-topic, and this constitutes a "high amount".
2. The moderator was incorrect in his reason to lock the post.
3. There are a "high amount" of deleted comments I cannot see which were off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *see* four. There are also 37 deleted comments on that post. ;)

Generally if you see that post notice, you can assume that most if not all of the off-topic comments have already been deleted. The lock is to prevent *more* comments from appearing.

Comment: Ah...so guess #3 then. Do I have to be a mod to see deleted comments?

Comment: @Paul Yes. Only mods can see them.

Comment: @PaulDraper I saw most of the comments before they were deleted. You aren't missing anything important `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake, no probably not :)