# Naming convention for Stack Overflow chatrooms?

Tags: discussion, chat, display-names

Some time back I came across a chat room created on [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) named as [**Java Sucks**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23658/java-sucks). I wanted to flag about the name of the chat room, but didn't find any way to do it. Nevertheless, I thought that some moderator would come across it and eventually it will get blocked.

Today, after few months when I saw it again. I went through the details and found that the first message was posted in the room in **2013-01-30**, which means the room has been in existence for over an year and half now.

I am under the impression think that **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)** *treats all the programming languages ***equally****. But, when chatrooms, with such names, are created, they create a bad impression for the language as well as the SO as a whole.

*Shouldn't we have some functionality where we can flag a **chat room**, so as to bring it into attention of the moderators?*

Or at least

*Can [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) list a set of rules for naming chatrooms?*

Comment: As a [tag:Java] user, I wholeheartedly agree with this.

Comment: @Unihedron me too. Java does indeed suck.

Comment: This is going to be a very impartial discussion :)

Comment: I'm not a Java user, but even I know that it sucks.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have to code in Java but really, I don't get the fuss, I wouldn't care if somebody had fun in a room whose name was an insult to my favourite language...

Comment: As a sidenote, you can always go in the room and flag any of the messages on the room for moderator attention. There's a free text field that allows you to type whatever you want.

Comment: Everyone can create a chat room. I'd argue that as long as it has anything to do with programming, that it's acceptable. Just don't create a room about your barbie doll collection.

Comment: Please don't use obscene language here or atleast censor it. Like J**A.

Comment: PHP also sucks. One of our [highest starred](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=18425506#18425506) messages will attest to this. Try not to take things like this too seriously...

Comment: To be honest, if you don't like the idea that Java sucks and want to stay away from it at all cost (being oblivious to the problems is the first step towards fixing them, after all) you want this room to exist: it keeps the discussion about Java sucking outside the Java room so you can continue living in your Java-is-wonderful-and-rainbows bubble of the Universe.

Comment: Any problem with this naming?Relax it's just a name.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As for rules for naming chat rooms, I believe the following are being applied these days.

- Does it mention [rightfold's vagina](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255221/46642)? If yes, it's not appropriate.

I don't see how rooms cannot be named in any way that its denizens deem appropriate for on-topic discussion. If people discuss the suckage of Java in said room, you would be hard-pressed to find a more appropriate title than "Java sucks".

Comment: Those rules make sense

Answer (score 35):

I don't think we should forbid such names. So someone doesn't like a language you like.

- The room has a topic that relates to programming.
- People in that room discussed programming in a language.
- They did not like a technology you do.

Basically, you're suggesting banning on-topic programming language discussion because the room owners do not agree with you on whether or not a particular programming language is good.

I'm also pretty sure moderators - who frequent the chat - are well aware of there existing rooms like "PHP sucks" or "Java sucks" etc. I think that they're perfectly fine and we should not interfere with rooms unless they cause abuse.

Now on the other hand if a room is abusive towards *users* that's a whole other story but I think that banning programming discussion on the premise we disagree with the opinion the people having the discussion have isn't something we want to do.

<sup>Plus - Java *is* a pretty horrible language after all</sup>

Comment: Just erase all the answer text, but the last line

Comment: I am Java developer and I find the last line offensive.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto please explain how the last line is offensive.

Comment: The discussion is about room names , it's not about any language in particular.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, that could only imply that such an opinion is offtopic, not that it's offensive...

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Again with the taking things too seriously. This is not a personal attack on you or any individual, it is merely an opinion that is opposed to yours - and a joke at that. Yes, it's somewhat superfluous to the answer itself, but it's a *joke*. I'm a PHP developer, people tell me PHP sucks all the time (which it does, by the way, much like *any other language*) and I do not get offended.

Comment: Well, I'm a PHP developer. And - yes, __PHP sucks__

Comment: So in that case you can not say bad about any language. All language have own set of ways of doing things. It's up to you if you like it or not. The counting of Java developer is more than any other language. There must be some interesting things about it  . I hope you'll understand it.

Comment: Just take it easy :-p Nothing is perfect - and, looking to the things with humor will definitely make your life better :-p

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto My point entirely. You can't say that no-one can say anything bad about any language, the only other indiscriminate option is that anyone can say anything about any language. Which is the status quo. And the way it should be. It's not like the room is called "Java f\*\*\*\*\*g sucks, and all Java developers are fags" or something - that *would* be offensive and unjustifiable and would not be tolerated.

Comment: I find it funny how one can say "It's up to you if you like it or not", and then find it offensive when someone does not like it.

Comment: You should have read the first line of that comment. @R.MartinhoFernandes

Comment: Wait. So you say that it's ok for you to not like it, *but it is not ok to express that opinion of yours*?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.  xD

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with a fitting response that does not consist of "sincerely, GFY". I live in a place where we value freedom of expression, and Stack Overflow is based in another such place. I do not condone that kind of censorship, and I expect Stack Overflow to behave in a similar manner.

Answer (score 6):

I don't feel like there's a real need to do anything you proposed:

- Naming convention - Rooms topics change, and so can their names. I'm not familiar with any chat platform that enforces room name rules (except for, perhaps, to prevent profanity). "Java sucks" is not profanity, it's something you disagree on, and it is said in the spirit of humor.
- Flagging chat rooms - You can flag any message for moderator attention (note, this is a different flag than the generic spam/abuse flag) from the message menu. You get a free text field so you can describe your concerns, and a moderator would look at it.

As for chat name rules, the same applies as it is for everywhere. Don't do something you wouldn't want to be done to you, and don't name your chatroom something other reasonable people would find offensive.