# Request for community attention on a moderator's behavior

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation, moderators

It has come to a handful of people's attention that at least some of the newly elected moderators might not be exactly up to challenge.
Here's a message that very clearly demonstrates this incompetence, that was a result of a particular argument that appeared in one of the SO chatrooms:

> *Madara Uchiha wrote:*

> > This room was placed in timeout for 2 minutes; the topic of this room is "We offer degrees in type seduction. " - conversation should be limited to that topic.
> > Let's get this straight.
> > We don't disallow swearing in our chatrooms
> > We don't prevent you from saying what you want.

> > But when we see you discussion about how girls prefer having sex, what are we supposed to think?
> > I don't really care about how you discuss here
> > But there is a limit
> > And that limit was reached.
> > The reaction from the user absolutely did not help, so it escalated.

> > If you don't want mods intervention, don't do things that require mod intervention.

> *Bartek Banachewicz wrote:*
>
> > @MadaraUchiha not to sound aggressive or anything, but IIRC you became a mod a few days ago. I don't think declaring a war on lounge is the best way to start your modding career.

> *Madara Uchiha wrote:*
>
> > @BartekBanachewicz Are you sure?
> > Because I've had a really long day, **and a war sounds very good to me. Test me.**

<sup>*(emphasis added)*</sup>

**[Full transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27232001#27232001)**

This would've been perfectly fine if it came from one of the debating parties. The individuals here are very passionate and discussions tend get heated. However, this came *from a moderator*, someone who's supposed to maintain professionalism.

---

Now, to be fair, this wasn't just a lone message. The context for that message in particular was a message from one user that was ultimately deemed inappropriate by the moderators (despite it being quite harmless to everyone else). As it often happens with such cases, the actual problem was blown out of proportion. Sometimes this happens because someone suddenly chooses to reach into chat transcript to find and analyze all possibly inappropriate messages. Sometimes, like this time, a person doesn't stop after a ban is inflicted on someone. What was done in this case is the person first said that

> We don't prevent you from saying what you want.

Followed by locking the room to make a personally appointed statement, followed by what turned out to be a provocative demonstration of power.

---

This behavior, of course, is unacceptable. A moderator should be a person *above* such discussions. Becoming a moderator implies that the user promises to moderate (and mediate!). *Actively provoking* like in the observed case, when it's full known that the person possesses moderator privileges and is essentially *threatening* to use them is a strong indication that the person might not be perfectly fit for the role.

This means that the community may have failed at picking an appropriate curator. Mistakes *do* happen; after all, we're only human, and if these mistakes happen, they *should* be able to be fixed. Moderator status is a privilege which should be able to be revoked by the same body of people that had granted it: the community.

Comment: So you're complaining because a mod used an entirely warranted moderation action in response to repeated inappropriate behavior from users who felt that the new mod wouldn't dare actually use their mod tools in response to said inappropriate behavior?  I'm not seeing a problem here at all.  Even your quote, taken entirely out of context, seems only mildly aggressive, and in context seems entirely fine.  Being a mod doesn't mean you have to act like a kindergarden teacher.

Comment: From an outsider/mod perspective, it really feels like there's some cherry picking going on. Bookmarking the actual context and linking it would be awesome.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The chat transcript is linked in the question.  The quote itself is a link to the context.

Comment: @Servy There's a fine line between "I'm a moderator, calm down" and "I'm a moderator and I can do whatever I want".

Comment: @JeremyBanks why? You're supposed to assess the contents, not the poster.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz And I'm saying that he's very clearly on the former side of that line.  He's not saying he'll do whatever he wants, he's saying that if you break the rules, you'll face the appropriate consequences, and that he won't just back down from taking an appropriate moderation action just because he's new.

Comment: [consider context](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/war) Someone *else* accuses him of making war first. Since I'm not a SO chat regular, care to fill in the peanut gallery on what actually sparked the room timeout?

Comment: @Bartek: Someone with more experience would probably have done a better job writing this post (from the same perspective) and would have had more credibility.

Comment: @JeremyBanks This was written by a collective group of people, and it's written in the perspective of these people.

Comment: @JeremyBanks You have no idea what you're talking about - this post is not made by a single user. Just wild speculation...

Comment: Reputation doesn't equal experience anyway. Or anything.

Comment: "written by a collective", so, is there a Github repo?

Comment: @brasofilo Of course :)

Comment: @Nooble, I suppose then that this "the community" that wants to revoke a mod's election is composed of many thousand users (how many?)

Comment: Edited to add context. Kinda dishonest quoting half of a sentence from a 5-6 paragraph exchange...

Comment: Also related: [the last time The Lounge was frozen.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191220/lounge-c-frozen-by-mod) Note that the last time this happened, it wasn't a two-minute timeout... Perhaps the newb mistake here was trying to conduct a conversation instead of just shutting the room down and imposing some order.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Do note that we decided not to post this, but Nooble did it anyway.

Comment: Well, that didn't take long.  You can practically set your watch by the time it takes between the completion of a moderator election and the first complaints to show up on Meta.

Comment: Is sending the freshly elected mods to the Lounge some kind of rite of passage?

Comment: @GregorMcGregor Yup, it's our version of hazing.  Care to have a go we have pretty high expectations?

Comment: @bluefeet judging by today's events, I'd say most Lounge members would do a much better job of moderating that situation than current freshmen.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That sentiment would mean something if you weren't one of the people causing the problem in the first place.  That you seem to think that "no moderation" == "good moderation" is exactly the problem here.

Comment: @Servy I have no idea what gave you an impression that I believe no moderation is a good idea. What I am against though, is blindly following the rules without giving a thought whether they apply to situation at hand and not taking the culture of the society you're moderating into account.

Comment: And FWIW there were perhaps more experienced moderators in the past, one of them certainly being @BoltClock, who managed to get along with Lounge reasonably. I don't have to tell you that from a few dozen people in this conversation *one* was enough to change to flip it all over. Yet you're still blaming the other few dozen for that.

Comment: I hope the voting on this question lets our new moderators know that most of us have faith in them and hope they keep at it :)

Comment: @JeremyBanks Just FYI, the Lounge has plenty of regulars with over 100k rep. I can't speak for everyone but I know the majority of them would've made this post instead of Nooble if asked. It seems you based your initial reaction off OP's rep, rather than the content itself.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Agreed. I think the jokes were made in poor taste, but this situation got out of hand real fast. It was a mistake to start off this discussion in an antagonistic tone. It's kind of too late to have a legitimate discussion anymore though, as Brad's post is on the top and sehe's is on the bottom. It doesn't matter what the context is; people are going to make up their minds about this as soon as they read what Brad had to say.

Comment: Shortly after that discussion the following message was posted: "...and some mods have shown themselves to be filth who don't deserve air to breathe, not to mention moderator privileges." It was flagged and removed, which lead to protests from pretty much the entire room. If almost an entire room seems incapable of constructive discourse it is no wonder that these situation tend to just blow up instead of being resolved quietly.

Comment: Speaking as a complete outsider: why are you using SO chat?  Just find an IRC server with the hands-off moderation you want.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with Madara's Reaction here. In fact, seeing this makes me happy that I swayed from my original vote set to vote for him.

Comment: @MadScientist tbh if I was a moderator, such a message would be a 2 week timeout to get some air and perspective for the poster.

Comment: I mean can't these people set up an online community elsewhere to have these types of discussions? Or is that just too revolutionary an idea. It's a public site.. what do people expect.

Comment: @Magisch yes I agree, both Madara and Ed handled it well. I really like the way Madara didn't buckle under the pressure. It shows a person of principle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a tirade/witch hunt.

Comment: TBH, I wouldn't mess with @Madara, (spoiler alert) I've seen what he's done to the shinobi army, joke aside... He acted well, behavior like this should not be tolerated. Props to Madara

Comment: Wait, this was the Lounge?  Nuke it from orbit. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not propose any change to process or procedure that would improve Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TylerH This is pretty explicitly on-topic, and the situation under discussion isn't resolved. If calling out moderators isn't acceptable ("witch hunt!") than we may as well stop holding elections. Holster your close votes and let lose with up/downvotes instead.

Comment: @JeremyBanks It's pretty well resolved based on *multiple* moderator responses and community voting, actually, but was largely resolved from the get-go thanks in no small part to the OP's total lack of understanding of the theory of moderation and the concept of moderated communities. This question is a tantrum thrown about a moderator for daring to moderate a room (aka do their job) that previously existed with impunity. If there is a substantive complaint here, it's only with Madara's tone, and the question needs to be heavily edited to reflect that before that can be answered.

Comment: No one will fall for this charade. He will be a moderator tomorrow, your room will stop being so offensive or run away to another chat provider.

Comment: @JeremyBanks how do you see it getting resolved as you say

Comment: @Drew The last time the room was frozen, the thread was closed several months later *when the situation was clearly stabilized*. The current situation is not stable: mods and CMs have been engaging with the room was recently as this past hour.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Regardless of what tag was used, the format of the site is still Q&A, and right now it's not Question & Answer, it's Witch Hunt & Seek A Burning At The Stake. As far as prolonging the discussion; Close Votes don't prevent comments, only answers. I figured you would know this with such high rep. Further, comments on an answer downvoted-into-oblivion won't be doing anything to keep the discussion "open", because, again, CVs aren't designed to stop new comments, only new answers.

Comment: While I would really prefer that [Rule 386](https://xkcd.com/386/) be invoked (at least under some of the answers) via locking, I doubt that would actually get things back on the rails. Still, closure of this question isn't justified when it so clearly involves and interests many (highly-active) SO users. I'm not certain what further input can be provided here, but my failure to imagine it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist, and I'd much rather see it in the form of an answer than more endless comments. Voting to reopen, and then going back to coding.

Comment: Reopening this. It's nominally on-topic, and although I'd advised the room regulars to let it drop, they appear to be all about continuing the argument as long as possible - therefore, I'm using their responses here as input in a proposal I'm drafting for new chat guidelines. As the old saying goes: when life gives you lemons, rub them all over and enjoy the sensation.

Comment: @Shog9: What's the benefit of re-opening this, as opposed to leaving it closed (But not deleted)? Does this question need a new answer?

Comment: @Shog9 All right, I've been thinking. When life gives you lemons, don't make lemonade. Make life take the lemons back! Get mad! I don't want your damn lemons! What am I supposed to do with these?! Demand to see life's manager! Make life rue the day it thought it could give Cave Johnson lemons! Do you know who I am? I'm the man who's gonna burn your house down! With the lemons! I'm gonna get my engineers to invent a combustible lemon that burns your house down!

Comment: @Cerbrus You don't close meta questions just because you don't agree with them, don't like what they're proposing, etc.  The question is on topic, and the discussions, while heated, have been largely constructive.  If you don't like what the OP is proposing then vote/answer accordingly.  There's no reason for the question to be closed though.  Questions also don't get closed just because you like the existing answers, there's no, "the existing answers are good enough" close reason, and for good reason.

Comment: @Servy: I'd appreciate if you didn't assume my reasons to close-vote a thread are just because I don't like something about it.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well you've voted to close the question using a close reason that very clearly doesn't apply.  Feel free to explain why you think the question should be closed, even though it doesn't meet any of the close criteria, if you don't want people to have to make assumptions.

Comment: @JeremyBanks / Servy: The deleted "answer" was a textbook example of _"not an answer"_. It's another question. I think the close-vote reason ___did apply___, because this posts is just a big rant, filled with all kinds of strong language and opinionated expressions of anger / malcontent. This doesn't look like a post that is looking for a discussion. It looks more like a post made to defame a moderator. Just because you're of the opinion that the chose closure reason doesn't apply, doesn't make it so.

Comment: Well the OP asked for community attention on a moderator's behaviour and no moderation can be examined in isolation of the facts leading up to and resulting from that moderation. And it's brought into light public behaviour that is considered to be unacceptable for this community. The SO community did not seek out this room, the room users sought moderator attention (through flags) and then demanded community attention by posting here and defending the right to behave badly at the cost of alienating the good will of the majority of community members. The price of adulthood, accountability.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it singles out and slams an individual and serves no constructive purpose on the site, except to expose an inappropriate subset of our community. This needs to be addressed in a post designated to dealing with this inappropriate behaviour and making members accountable for their actions. Beyond this, it serves only to divide the community and leave a public footprint that brings disgrace upon our community, caused by  a minority.

Comment: @MrsEd Shog9 in his most recent comment above has mentioned he is drafting a post to cover new Chatroom rules already to (hopefully) prevent situations like this question from happening again.

Comment: @TylerH yeh, thanks for that, that was pointed out to me after I had made the vote. I considered withdrawing my close vote, but thought, I stand by the reasons. If the SO team are not happy with this, they can let me know.

Comment: @CloseVoters: The question has been reopened by moderators multiple times. I don't see the point in wasting your close votes on this question when you can be certain that it will be reopened. While I agree with all of the sentiments around it's closure, the question itself *is* on-topic. There are much less wasteful things you could be doing with your time.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Imo, _"Waste of time"_ isn't a very strong argument. It's not like close-voting requires a significant amount of effort. In fact, that comment you posted takes a heck of a lot more ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus If you know that it is just going to be reopened, what is the point in voting to close it? What exactly are you trying to accomplish by performing an action that you know is going to be invalidated?

Comment: @TinyGiant it's a vote. At very least, it's an indication of how many people think the question should be closed.

Comment: _"This would've been perfectly fine if it came from one of the debating parties."_ Wrong.

Answer (score 153):

This is an extremely distorted depiction of what happened in the C++ Lounge earlier today.

What actually happened was this: Stack Overflow moderators received several flags about offensive messages in the C++ Lounge. Among the messages that we saw in that chatroom was the following (warning: language):

> Most women want at least something of a date before they fuck. The ones who don't, you (or certainly I, anyway) probably want to avoid.

When confronted about this completely inappropriate conversation happening in a public chatroom, several members of this room fought back against moderators and SE staff. One of them told an SE staff member

> breaking news, you can't dare consider women are more than just fuck bags

and then proceeded to be rude and abusive to said staff member in a private chat. They were suspended from the site. This further set off other members of this chatroom.

Madara Uchiha has taken a more active role in moderating chat, and has attempted to bridge the gap in rooms where we've had behavioral issues and complaints. I think he's actually done a very good job of this. He, along with Ed Cottrell, decided to step in and try to make it clear that this kind of behavior is completely unacceptable on this site.

Again, this [was not responded to in a constructive manner](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27231175#27231175). You can read the whole transcript around that comment, if you'd like. I think it was simply frustration with the whole C++ Lounge coming out, since members of that Lounge feel that they are above the rules of this site.

Frankly, if it were up to me, I'd freeze the whole room and be done with it. The C++ Lounge has been getting away with completely unacceptable and unprofessional behavior for years. I welcome the members of the Stack Overflow community to read the last few days of the transcript from the Lounge and to give us a reason why this chatroom should be allowed to continue.

Comment: One thing that's certainly way misleading here is that Madara didn't try to *bridge* anything. Has he actually tried to talk to the folk in the Lounge, which promptly tried to illustrate the CONTEXT of the offending message, this could look wholly different. Instead, he chose to ignore that and pronounce his power in a provocative manner.

Comment: The original message is not offensive and you'd be hard pressed to argue that it's even wrong. It's a life anecdote. And in the second you still hone in on OMG A BAD WORD with regex-like accuracy and completely disregard the entire meaning of the thing you're quoting (which is the exact opposite of trying to call women that). Is it hostile? Yes, it is. That's because mods decided to harass a valuable member of the community for absolutely no reason at all. Oh and don't forget trying to silence opposition by reducing everything into "trolling" and instabanning so you can't even argue. Woopee.

Comment: But it's easier to derail the entire thing as "omg you're so unconstructive and unprofessional" than to admit that maybe you overreacted in the first place.

Comment: The "breaking news" message was *after* the user who said was already suspended once for no reason, by the way.

Comment: Sometimes, I'm not sure some Loungers have a good idea of what "professionalism" actually means...

Comment: @ElimGarak - Other chatrooms don't get flagged for conversations about women "liking rape" (which horrified multiple moderators from other sites when they saw it earlier today). This doesn't happen in other chatrooms, only the Lounge. Why is that?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I see over a dozen posts by Madara preceding the quote in the OP that are entirely reasonable attempts to explain and dissolve the situation.  This was met with hostility and repeated inappropriate behavior by others, challenging their very right to enforce the moderation policies *that they are required to uphold*.  That this eventually culminated, after repeated attempts to dissolve the situation, in the statement that he would not in fact back down to threats by others and held firm in his position that he'd enforce the site's rules is exactly what I'd *expect* of a mod.

Comment: All the times, I'm fairly sure people using the word "professionalism" are not worth listening to.

Comment: Ok I was on the fence until the rape thing. Shut it down. Jeez.

Comment: @Brad if a message gets flagged in a room, and you think the message is inappropriate, doesn't that mean the system is working as intended? I could stop by any other room and post absolutely anything - would you consider that to be that room's fault?

Comment: There are limits to what one should/can say. People always seem to forget that.

Comment: @Bartek, No, it doesn't. [This has happened before on other sites.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7588/whats-next-for-chat?cb=1) When there's a deeper problem with the culture of a chatroom, the only thing flags can do is handle the symptoms. Further action is needed to handle the cause.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz When, in response to said flagged content being moderated, the rest of the room starts objecting to the moderation of the content, continues posting more inappropriate content, and starts picking fights with the moderators to claim that they don't have the right to moderate the room, I'd say yes, holding the room accountable for that would be appropriate.  Had one person said one bad thing, the content been flagged, removed, and everyone else been glad to be rid of the inappropriate content, that would be different.

Comment: The rape message was from like 2 days ago from some user I think I never saw around.

Comment: [Oh, really? Here's "rape" in the PHP room.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=rape&room=11)... So tell me, where do you draw the line? We could scour the transcript of every room for stuff that falls through the cracks of flagging.

Comment: Transparency 104: post some claims about something, but don't post any evidence, because Mods Are Infallible.

Comment: You volunteering, @Elim? Let's clean house...

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I would sincerely hope that a comment such as that would have been deleted, so it wouldn't be in a transcript to link to.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - So here's the thing about that awful comment I posted above. It was only found when someone read the transcript, because apparently members of the room were instructed not to flag it: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/27182392/history . That's members of the room intentionally circumventing the system to protect themselves, and I find that completely unacceptable.

Comment: This "liking rape" allegation - is it more than an urban myth? If that thing is literally true, and not a lone act of provocation or blown way out of proportion, then I'll personally vouch for deletion of the room. (Hint, I'm not buying it yet)

Comment: You know that EVERY ROOM intentionally "circumvents the system" because "the system" is completely goddamn ANNOYING and ineffective? Which was reported on meta and subsequently ignored multiple times even?

Comment: @Servy point being in this particular case the vast majority of people in the chatroom who actually were able to read and comprehend the context of the message didn't deem it inappropriate. Stating that aloud isn't a riot you're trying to paint it as; it's a massive disagreement which was swept under the rug of aforementioned "trolling" and "picking fights".

Comment: @sehe - That was this comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27182384#27182384 right above yours about not flagging things.

Comment: @BradLarson I resent that. THIS agreement has been made with Jon Clement on his PARTICULAR, REPEATED request. Ask Mysticial. Scan the transcript for "UNDERSTANDING". Wow.

Comment: @BradLarson looking. Hold on

Comment: @BradLarson That was in direct response to mods complaining about the number of flags. Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Comment: do: behave don't: misbehave so things need to be flagged. Damned: Misbehave, and cover it up. Seems simple to me,.

Comment: @BradLarson Can we have a private chat? (Or public for that matter)

Comment: @Brad it's not to protect the members of the chatroom - it's to protect every user above 10k rep from endless spam of flags, which **other rooms have been doing as well** for quite some time already.

Comment: `EVERY ROOM intentionally "circumvents the system" because "the system" is completely goddamn ANNOYING and ineffective...` -- Nice straw man, there.

Comment: @Servy: I don't. Message deletions are net negative because transparency, which is far more important than the misguided political correctness, "cleanness", protecting whoever from words, or whatever the today's excuse is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Strawman? We're not even arguing for god's sake. Nice derail tactic. This is facts: rooms try to settle things in rooms first because the flags lack context or knowledge of the situation and are largely false positives. Hell, you people told us to try to make people flag less, because it annoys both mods and every single 10k user on the chat. This is what the supposed "circumvention" is about. So yeah strawman as hell.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus So you don't think *highly* inappropriate content should ever be removed, because if it is, you couldn't prove to someone else that the inappropriate content was said?  The fact that you apparently don't think that any content should be moderated simply tells me that you shouldn't be on an SE chat in the first place.  You're not looking for a professional chat room, you're looking for an entirely casual unmoderated chat room.  That's fine, and there's god knows ho many of those on the internet.  Why are you trying to hang out on one that doesn't feel that any content is allowable?

Comment: @Servy It can be hidden, whatever, it shouldn't be made inaccessible as it is right now. You can punish people without destroying evidence, yes. Transparency is important, which today's situation kinda critically proves? Also I'm here for the people, which is why I care enough to bother trying to argue in this stupid upvote-ridden format designed to hide unpopular side of the argument. (And there it is, that "professional" word again. I swear *that* should be autobannable.)

Comment: I have to say the whole confusion about flag usage and then both appearances of flags and lack of thereof being used against the Lounge shows a rather peculiar approach to executing the praised site policies. Esp given that we can't backtrack the whole history in all cases because that's a mod-only privilege.

Comment: ...Right.  To answer the question posed in this answer (ironically enough), enough is enough.  I trust the mods' judgment enough in this scenario to do what's best for the site on this one.  If this means that this chatroom is nuked from orbit, I'll supply the ICBMs if need be.

Comment: Blindly trusting mods is the very problem we're trying to highlight here, so good job?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus:  I'll admit:  the way you're arguing about this doesn't do your side any favors.  I've looked at the evidence and I'm inclined to agree with much of what has transpired on the part of the mods.

Comment: @Makoto Haven't you heard tone arguments kinda fell out of favour a long time ago.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus How has this situation proven that we need more transparency?  There's been plenty of transparency by the mods here to show that there was more than enough inappropriate behavior to warrant all of the actions that they've taken, and they've been very open about exactly what they've done and why.  Again, if you want to participate in chat rooms that never delete anything, ever, there's a few million of them out there for you to use.  The SE chat isn't The Wild West.  Inappropriate content will be removed.  If that isn't what you want, then why are you here?

Comment: If you're going to nuke the Lounge, you will have to nuke every other "professional" chat room on SO. So, just shut down chat. Because the "trigger words" for moderators can be easily found in every room. It just so happens that the Lounge is one of the biggest rooms, so (go figure) bad jokes happens more often.

Comment: @Servy you cannot judge it. I'm still here waiting for the to pick up the phone... So much for due diligence

Comment: I just spent about 35 minutes reading the transcript for the C++ room and have to say that it looks just as bad as some of the worst reddit threads I've seen. #disgusted

Comment: @ElimGarak I think it's been shown very clearly that this is in no way just blind reaction to isolated words devoid of context.  Taken in context, all of the quoted comments that have been given as examples really are highly offensive, and intentionally so.  This isn't the case of someone just f\*cking including some d\*mn swearwords in inoffensive statements.

Comment: @Servy Can you please explain what is offensive about the very original message "Most women want at least something of a date before they fuck. The ones who don't, you (or certainly I, anyway) probably want to avoid."? And please, for the love of God and all that is holy, don't go down the "Well, if you can't see it, then that's the problem" path.

Comment: @Jefery He wasn't suspended for that one comment alone.  That comment just caused mods to join the room and tell people to tone it down.  The response to being told that such discussions aren't appropriate was what resulted in the suspensions and room freeze.

Comment: @Makoto and what exactly do you think will be achieved by closing that room? If a new C++ room appears, the situation might not change at all. If it doesn't, the outside flaggers will bubble out in other rooms.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz:  Peace and quiet, for one thing.  No more chat melodrama on Meta that seems to have been well covered by mods.

Comment: @Servy That comment was deleted by one of the mods. His reaction to that derives from that action. Can you explain that action? What is there to "tone it down" in that message? What's out of line?

Comment: @Makoto and why do you think having a room with a particular number corresponds to that drama? Or will you force the community to split into multiple rooms? Or will you ban everyone from chat outright? Because if it's the latter, you'd need proper case like this one set against each and every one.

Comment: You were not even smart about it. You managed to pick Jerry out. I mean what the actual fuck? He probably is one of the most respectable people you'll even find on SO. Years of contributions, thousands points of reputations always very calm and respectful.

Comment: @Jefery And yet, which is worth noting, given his outstanding reputation both with regard to programming and the community interactions, he chose "filth" to describe some of the moderators involved.

Comment: @Jefery I'm mostly concerned with the community's response than to the initial comment.  *That* is where I see the most inappropriate and worrisome behavior.  Had the response been constructive arguments for why you feel that such content is appropriate, nobody would ever have been suspended, the room would never have been locked, and everyone would already have forgotten about the whole thing by now.

Comment: @Servy What response to that initial comment? The response you see in the transcript was to the removal of that comment from a mod. Why was that message removed? What's inappropriate about it?

Comment: Oh snap, I'm all outta popcorn. Keep up the constructive discussions while I get some more...

Comment: @TinyGiant That hurts.

Comment: Brad, perhaps you should pull the petition to shut down Lounge<C++> out into its own question so we can see the community response slightly more clearly. This needs all the visibility we can get on it.

Comment: Speaking as a newer member of the community, after reading through about 2 days of transcripts, you should really just close that room down.

Comment: Well - chat flags [are terrible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203346/flags-in-chat-are-defective-by-design) a big part of why I campaigned for @Madara is so there can be more people with power to moderate in chat because the flags are broken.

Comment: @Magisch if we're gonna get that ridiculous compare what you said with "I am an older member of the community, and I have read through *years* of transcripts, and you should really not just close that room down". See also https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=thanks&user=&room=10.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't see any justification in that for the vitriol that even 2 days of chatlogs show. Quite contrary. I don't think the moderators would be overreacting by deleting the chatroom and sending some of the worst offenders on a year of chat hiatus.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That's _22402 messages_. [Guess what room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=thanks&user=&room=17) has ___27595___ _"thanks"_ messages? And not nearly as many "Offensive" flags. ;-)

Comment: @Magisch what does deleting the room accomplish? It essentially boils down to this: am I persona non grata here? I would like to be told so, so I can go my way. Otherwise, I will be around, chatting. The room doesn't affect that. Getting rid of it is just a propagandistic measure.

Comment: As a former member of the room, something I'd much prefer over just deleting the room: moderate it. It's part of SO's community. Own it. Take responsibility for it. You can close it, and turn away some extremely knowledgeable and helpful users which would honestly be a loss to SO, or you can take responsibility for making the room less toxic. Not by banning off-topic "lounge" talk in general, but by making it happen in a respectful manner. There's a lot of good about the Lounge, and I hope it can continue, for the sake of SO and the Lounge community. But it could stand to lose the toxicity

Comment: A year ago I'd have argued that the room should just be left alone to continue as it is, but really... letting the place steep in the atmosphere of casual racism and misogyny it's bred doesn't seem like a viable long-term solution. And heck, Reddit has shown how ineffective the "containment" strategy is. You can't have one place where bad behavior is allowed and hope for it to be contained there.

Comment: @jalf What makes you say that there is an atmosphere of "casual racism and misogyny"? I have personally see very little of either in the room. Do you have practical examples?

Comment: I haven't, yet, read all the comments, but this is music to my ears. Just because it's been going on for years, doesn't mean it should continue (as some people seem to equate longevity of behaviour with acceptability of such). There's nothing to stop people from forming a social chat somewhere else off site. Anything that raises the bar of standards for the site gets a vote from me. This doesn't mean we can't joke and have fun.. but seriously, out of the gutter. A show of such good community support against this behaviour is a big plus in restoring any outsiders view of us (the SO community).

Comment: @Jalf Moderate it? Like they did just now? how many people jumped up and fought against it? Not saying moderation isn't the way to go, but when a room such as the lounge has been allowed to fester the way it festered for so long, there's not much to do. If you try to revert the behavior, you get a small sub-community that posts stuff like "we should revert the voting of Madara as mod"... How many users in the lounge? Vs how many votes for Madara? This just shows how the chat room acts, and believes they are more important to the community than the community itself.

Comment: Is there any outsiders' view of the Lounge C++ chat room?  Are there any 'Why do some people hate Stack Overflow Lounge++ chat?' sites?

Comment: Patrice, I'd consider myself a regular in the Lounge. I voted for Madara and Ed and I would gladly vote for them again. I would urge you to join us in the Lounge for a day (you too @MrsEd ) when this situation cools down. I think you'll find we are not as terrible as you've been made to believe.

Comment: @nick I'm not saying it's currently terrible, I'm just saying that someone stepping up and going "well we can moderate the lounge", when the last time someone tried moderation... THIS happened, might be misguided. I honestly read the transcripts, and I randomly read left and right in the chat history of the lounge. I think I'd fit, you guys have a very dry, cynical humor that seems REALLY similar to mine. I'm not debating THAT part of it. I'm debating the reaction to moderation, and how hard this simple moderating act seems to have kicked up dust.

Comment: If a sub-group is so AGAINST being moderated, then I question why they are on a moderated site. That's pretty much my only take of this right now. No matter WHAT the actual moderation act is. When something gets moderated, users rant, throw up tantrums, start witch hunts, get ever MORE insulting... this isn't constructive in ANY way. Has nothing to do with the comment (which I don't find that terrible. In poor taste for a public site? Maybe... but I truly don't give a flying F about it), just with the Lounge's reaction to it.

Comment: @nick thanks for that. Your remark is tempered in such a heated discussion. You are probably right. It's unfortunate that some of the most offensive material possible (there is worse, but not much) was made into a laughing matter and then there's this outcry of injustice. I know people who have been banned from chat for longer for less.

Comment: @Patrice Fair enough, and well said. I am not sure why some of the Loungers react so strongly to moderation.

Comment: @nick good question. I have no clue about it. Maybe so long without moderation made it a habit, so now moderation ALWAYS looks weird, no matter what? To me though, calling out that THEY want Madara out of diamond mod because THEY don't want him anymore shows how they consider the rest of the Stack community :S

Comment: I've already said that we've been moderated by both the room owners and other moderators and it was fine, so I've no idea why you're trying to generalize our reaction to this case into "they react to moderation badly". No, we **react badly to bad moderation** and that's what happened here. This is what the whole thread is about but apparently you're ignoring our PoV completely. I have no idea how saying "this mod reacted badly and should perhaps be reconsidered because his behaviour shows rather surprising patterns" is "considering the rest of SO community" in *whatever* way.

Comment: sparked the whole debate. It's the amount of vitriol I see here, and how it was thrown in the chatroom, that I find idiotic and pointless. All in all, it's (maybe, I don't even care about it) a bad moderation move, yes. Does that justify all this pointless noise? no. Not at all. This is my only point here. That you come back trying to say what Madara did wasn't okay only proves you don't read what I posted, or take things from MY PoV.

Comment: @Patrice I'm not asking for the vote to be **reversed**, I'm asking about **consideration** of what's happening here. We "bitched" in the chatroom because that's where the issue started. We brought it here because we couldn't resolve that with mods present.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz you aren't, but the OP here is, and this is a "community post" according to him... so.... Ok, and why does it make it okay to bitch in the chatroom? Why fan the flames? Most of the regulars seem to KNOW how Stack works.... why act against how it actually works and expect good results?

Comment: @Patrice the post literally says *is a strong indication that the person might not be perfectly fit for the role.* If you still see that as "hurr kick out madara durr", then I'm done here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz lol.... and again we go with the insulting and condescending tone. THIS is the problem man, nothing else. Look, the last paragraph of the OP is pretty clear as to what he(or the community that wrote it) thinks. If you want to be pedantic on the actual words being used, you're as bad as people who take your rapeseed comment to heart. In the context of this full post, the last paragraph saying "Moderator status is a privilege which should be able to be revoked by the same body of people that had granted it: the community" sounds pretty much like a call for a reversal, yes.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The post also literally says *"Here's a message that very clearly demonstrates this incompetence"* but glad to hear you're "done here".

Comment: I originally read the OP as being a request for a moderator's privileges to be taken away, or for a process for such action to exist, which would in a way be a feature request, no? It didn't seem to be asking for a discussion of whether or not the actions were justified, it explicitly stated that the actions were wrong and should be punished. The downvotes it received *I* think are a clear indicator that there are more people who disagree with the idea that the actions were wrong. So, it's a bit unclear what the original intent of this question was.

Comment: @Shog9 Are you inviting people to comb room transcripts and mass-flag offensive chatroom comments with your comment there?

Comment: Nope, @Magisch. Unless the alternative is forcing folks to stay silent when they see a problem, angrily defending bad behavior as acceptable "because that's how we've always done it", and refusing to consider that there are people with just as much a right to be here as yourself who might find such language off-putting... That's a false dichotomy and a horribly polarizing viewpoint... But if that's the only alternative you can imagine then *please* pick the side that lets you clean up trash over the side that forces you to wallow in it.

Comment: @Shog9 Its funny you should say that. I combed a little through some history in the chat room and flagged some obviously offensive comments and not only did the regulars there take joy in denying the flags, a moderator asked me to stop. I conclude in this that Stack Overflow does not wish for members to participate in chatroom moderation.

Comment: @Magisch: Perhaps they were only "obviously" offensive to you.  A few F words are not worth flagging; my guiding principle is "is some person or group likely to feel attacked?"

Comment: _The C++ Lounge has been getting away with completely unacceptable and unprofessional behavior for years_ - I don't think you know what professional means. No one is a professional Lounge member.

Answer (score 94):

I was debating posting my own answer, now that [Brad Larson's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311542/2057919) pretty much covers everything. But this post is about "the newly elected moderators," which obviously includes me, and I want to add a couple of comments that won't fit in a comment on Brad's answer.

The Lounge today veered well off the tracks, including a large number of obscene comments, including the ones that Brad quoted and some others that don't bear repeating here or anywhere else. This drew some flags and caught the attention of quite a few of the moderators.

Bluefeet, Jon Clements, Madara, and I attempted to steer the room back to civil conversation. None of the (many) moderators who were in the room at any point today tried to silence anyone. What we tried to do was address the most offensive and often obscene commentary during this isolated episode. I tried to be respectful to all involved, and I'm sure all of the other moderators who were in The Lounge today did the same.

Personally, I don't enjoy moderating chat, but it's a responsibility that comes with being a moderator. And as I've said before, everyone is welcome to have fun and have completely off-topic conversations in chat. Frankly, I personally don't care what people talk about. But the moderators have a job to do. That job is mostly janitorial work, and sometimes it boils down to sewage treatment, but somebody's got to do it.

We will continue to do our work professionally and as nicely as possible. That sometimes means deploying the tools at our disposal to suspend, ban, kick, or otherwise remove a user from a chat room. Sometimes, it means deleting an over-the-line post from the chat history. Sometimes, it means opening a private chat room with a user. Most times, it just means making some comments to steer things back on the tracks. We try the comments approach first; other approaches are deployed only when necessary.

Today, a few of the more severe approaches were necessary, and various moderators employed them. This happened because of the comments of users in The Lounge, including the comments that got our attention in the first place. We don't moderate what doesn't exist.

Comment: Keep weatherin' the storm.  Keep reinforcing my belief in the whole lot of you guys.

Comment: Thankfully there are heroes like you to steer that awful room back to "civil conversation".

Comment: @Jefery I am afraid not everyone will appreciate the irony.

Comment: @Jefery To be clear, I'm not saying that it had been in "civil conversation" territory anytime recently.

Comment: *We* have been uncivil? You know what's uncivil? Using mod powers to shut down people trying to reply to your accusations. That's uncivil and *unprofessional*.

Comment: @Jefery A two minute time out, to give people a moment to cool their heads, after spending over and hour explaining to people why, exactly the actions were taken, despite continued inappropriate and abusive responses from the community, (and then resuming said discussion immediately after that short time out) is not "shutting down people trying to reply to accusations".

Comment: @Servy No, I'm talking about banning Jerry, Cat and Cosh.

Comment: @Jefery No one got shut down and prevented from responding. If you mean the timeout, it had nearly zero impact on the conversation and was necessary to stall the flood of comments for a mere 2 minutes.

Comment: I'm not going to repeat myself.

Comment: @Jefery Cosh got suspended due his extremely over-the-top comments and rude behavior in one-on-one chat with a moderator. I don't know anything about bans or suspensions of the others.

Comment: @Jefery They demonstrated a complete inability to act civilly, and made it clear that they had no intention of constructively discussing the issue.  They weren't banned for disagreeing with a moderation action, they were banned due to the significant amounts of highly inappropriate content they were posting.  That someone disagrees with a mod doesn't excuse them from posting highly offensive and insulting material.

Comment: Then you clearly have all the infos to judge this event I see. Good job informing yourself before replying to this. It means a lot to me.

Comment: @Servy What "highly inappropriate content" was Cat posting?

Comment: @Jefery [Nevermind, Cat was clearly posting entirely constructive and reasoned arguments in response to the suspension that he disagreed with](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27231175#27231175).

Comment: @Jefery Those users also made some ban-worthy comments; I just don't know exactly how things went down.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Jefery asked me why you, specifically, were suspended, and claimed that your response to the initial banning was entirely constructive and didn't warrant such behavior.  The linked comment shows otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that one.

Comment: @Servy So you're just assuming and jumping to conclusions based on those assumptions. Gotcha. This wasn't initial banning, this was the second wave. Not that it makes any kind of difference, because do I really have to repeat 10 goddamn times that tone arguments are invalid I don't want to live on this planet please kill me

Comment: @Servy ALSO it was after the whole thing was started from literally NOTHING (because nothing Jerry said was bad or ~~~~offensive~~~~), so there's that.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus And had you expressed that sentiment constructively, you wouldn't have been suspended.  Instead you decided to protest your perceived moderation of appropriate behavior by posting content that you clearly knew (and intended to be) offensive.  That it resulted in the suspension (that you *literally asked for*) should not be surprising.  If you express your concerns about the rooms moderation constructively, then an actual dialogue can take place.

Comment: @Servy I don't care about my suspension very much (although I do believe it was incredibly silly). I care about suspensions of thecoshman and Jerry. Not sure why you even bring it up, because I wasn't suspended for SUSPEND THIS!!! anyway, but much later. I mean I know why you bring it up, because you don't know what happened, but you know, figure of speech.

Comment: Ed, I voted for you and I am pleased to have you on board as a moderator. A professional post here and although I'm not reinventing the wheel in anything I'm saying here. I merely offering you my voice of support as a community member. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 78):

[image: Chat Tire Fire]

Tire fires are [no joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire_fire):

> Extinguishing tire fires is difficult. The fire releases a dark, thick smoke that contains carbon monoxide, sulfur dioxide, and products of butadiene and styrene. Burning tires are heated and as they have a low thermal conductivity, they are difficult to cool down. Moreover, they frequently burn inside even if they are extinguished from outside, and easily reignite when hot.

I originally thought about tire fires as an analogy for another site altogether, but I'm afraid there are several chat rooms smoldering away around the network. It's only a question of which ones will flame up next. This time it was the C++ Lounge which isn't a stranger to spreading toxic fumes around:

- [Offensive, inappropriate, and un-professional chat room names](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255221/offensive-inappropriate-and-un-professional-chat-room-names/)
- [Lounge C++ frozen by mod?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191220/lounge-c-frozen-by-mod/191251)

I've heard from Stack Overflow moderators who want nothing to do with that room. It's got a rotten reputation among many hardened chat users. As long as I've been working as a Community Manager, the Lounge has been a by word of everything wrong with chat moderation. **We've known about this problem and we haven't done what's needed to put out the fire.**

Let's be clear: *chat [is bound](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#nice) to our [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.* What I read this afternoon goes far beyond the bounds of acceptable behavior. That some moderators (and a former moderator) chose to step in to mediate was courageous and welcome. They did a fine job considering the hostile environment they were working in.

---

I've seen many of the some bogus arguments tossed around when a chat room flares up:

1. > We always talk like this. It's our room culture.

   This is often true after a fashion. Some rooms are generally more crass than the rest of the network. As a [third place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place) that's not only natural, it's part of the chat system's function. But that does not make chat or any particular room a safe harbor for every type of crude behavior. If you don't have a filter to prevent crossing the line, your room doesn't really have a culture.
2. > *In context*, the chat message was not offensive.

   Context *is* critical to interpretation. But a wise user of chat must be aware that anything they say might be seen out of context. It's doubly true of chat message that are likely to draw flags. If people misunderstand the message because it depends on context, that's your fault, not theirs. Besides, when I look into situations like that, the context doesn't usually make those message innocent—context just makes them less horrific.
3. > If it weren't for those oversensitive flaggers, there'd be no problems here.

   Sure. And if there weren't any whistleblowers, corruption would never be detected either. The question isn't whether or not the person reporting the problem is oversensitive. Rather the question is if they are reporting a real problem. (Hint: the people handling chat flags [dislike bogus flags too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125192/let-me-opt-out-of-viewing-chat-flags).)
4. > It was a joke. I was being sarcastic.

   So, we've known for a long time that:

   > Without a clear indication of the author's intent, it is difficult or impossible to tell the difference between an expression of sincere extremism and a parody of extremism.—[Poe's Law](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Poe%27s_Law)

   The solution is similarly well-known, you moron. ;-)

   That said, no combination of emoticons will fix jokes that aren't funny or sarcasm that isn't insightful.

I don't know how to solve the problem, exactly. We could always try the tire fire solution:

> One possible remedy is to cover the fire with soil, reducing the supply of oxygen and the exhaust of smoke. After extinguishing and cooling down (which may last several days), toxic chemicals can be neutralized.

Comment: _"If people misunderstand the message because it depends on context, that's your fault, not theirs."_ Absolutely not. You're entering very dangerous territory there. I also don't understand how you can claim this a couple sentences after saying _"Context is critical to interpretation."_

Comment: @orlp: Yes. This is a good illustration of what I mean. The first quote taken out of context is clearly flawed. But I wrote the entire post and included the qualifying sentence beforehand. I hope that as a reader you will take both sentences together and try to make sense of them. I would not have that luxury if I'd posted this in chat, rather than as an answer.

Comment: Context does not always matter. if someone flagged (I am making this up) "I hate C++ template metaprogramming" then even out of context that is not bad: one may disagree with that opinion, but it is not offensive. Misogynist comments are rude, sexist, unprofessional, and have no place on this site _regardless_ of context.

Comment: @Snowman, the whole thing is misogynic of the worst kind and dudes are like "please, explain what's wrong with it?"... highly toxic tire burn indeed

Comment: @brasofilo oh I know, I saw enough. I have a fairly strong opinion on the matter that can best be summed up by **[xkcd: Free Speech](https://xkcd.com/1357/)**

Comment: @Snowman Talking about sex is not misogynistic for fuck's sake. Literally no thing said in this stupid thing has been. The unrelated singular rape joke earlier, yes, but that's a different matter than what this thread is about and nobody is arguing for it. But you know what, nevermind, enjoy your echo chamber.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: No talking about sex is not misogynistic. But the two messages Brad quoted in his answer aren't really about sex are they? Even if they are intended to be sarcastic, joking or over-the-top, they only tangentially relate to the most intimate act two humans can share. We know this because the messages were posted in a public chat room. I interpret them as being about power and conquest, but I could be wrong. If so, well, I wish they'd been phrased more appropriately for the medium.

Comment: @JonEricson I literally do not understand this post. Power and conquest? What. What Jerry said is a in-my-experience life anecdote and it's not even bad in any way shape or form (unless people wanting to date before sex is bad? Is that what I'm missing here?) and I do not follow any reasoning that arrives at construing it as hateful or demeaning towards women. I could say the same thing about myself, wow. thecoshman is reiterating the idea behind Jerry's message in fairly strong words but that's because it's well into the ban spree campaign and we were all fairly annoyed already.

Comment: @JonEricson Basically I'm assuming that I'm talking to reasonable people that can follow some form of consistent logic and what I'm seeing is the exact opposite of that, plus shitload of knee-jerk reactions and an alarming problem with reading comprehension. Which is frankly extremely annoying.

Comment: By the way nobody ever mentioned free speech because nobody here is a moron and we all know what free speech means, thanks.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Oh, wait. You were in the middle of a ban spree? Ok, now I totally understand everything.</sarcasm> Seriously, though, if you think amping up the strength of your language is a rational solution to other people objecting to your words, then you are in for a rather unpleasant future.

Comment: @JonEricson Yes that is an actionable thing we can work on. But that doesn't make the initial event any less of an extreme (and also damaging to our community) overreaction. Which is the fundamental problem I'm trying to highlight by apparently running into a judgemental talking wall over and over again.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I'm not judging you or your community. I am, however, disgusted with just about everything I read in your transcript this afternoon. If you are serious about fixing the problem with how people react to messages in the C++ Lounge, you should find ways to respond to flags and bans other than trolling for more.

Comment: `We could always try the tire fire solution` but a [concrete sarcophagus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_New_Safe_Confinement) would be so much safer!

Comment: So you link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191220/lounge-c-frozen-by-mod/191251, but fail to see/regard/point out [Caspar's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191226/133368) _which says_ ___the room should not have been frozen?___ Of course, that gives so much credit to the rest of your arguments.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus the comments were sexist, they were aimed at demoralising women, not men. If you truly would like to be at the receiving end next time there is talk like this in the C++ lounge, I'll be sure to join the conversation and give you a taste of the same and equally horrid treatment of men by women. I can assure you, it would leave most of the participants  feeling ill, demoralised and very angry. It's devisive and totally unnecessary here or really anywhere. It says a lot about the people using this kind of talk. And what it says it not good.

Comment: @MrsEd Please do, because by your interpretation of what's "demoralising" and "horrid" it'll be the most tame conversation in the history of the universe. The lack of reading comprehension going on is what's horrid. #disgusted

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I don't think that's something you should be proud of.

Comment: @GregorMcGregor get real. I'm not replying to any more of this. I'm glad I have a choice of whom to mix with.

Comment: @MrsEd Please do it.

Comment: @MrsEd What isn't. Nothing you say make any sense, it's just parroting the same nonsense over and over again without any hint of critical thought.

Comment: Regardless of how one splits hairs over whether the comments were misogynist, about sex in general, tame, invective, or anything else... why is this even a discussion? Chat guidelines are basically "stuff you could say around the water cooler at work." If I had heard _any_ of that stuff at the water cooler, y'all would be **fired**. Here we have representatives from Stack Exchange, who **own** the chat room, saying that what happened is not acceptable. Then we have others using this **free service that can be revoked** arguing the point. I just don't get it.

Comment: @Snowman Yes, fine.  OTOH, if some visitor to your offices turned up at the water-cooler and spouted off some grossly offensive remarks, would you fire your own staff who happened to be around at the time?

Comment: @MartinJames if that staff was present for many days around those comments but didn't seem to care, mind, or take any action to correct the visitor from making those sorts of comments consistently?

Comment: @enderland well, I certainly would, but whether I would expect my peers to agree or disagree, well, it's up to them..

Comment: @MrsEd: I agree entirely with the direction of your remarks. I'd add that the inherent misogyny in the discussion in question is amplified by mainstream culture's default sexism. For your theoretical suggestion that women should give (these kind of) men the same treatment, the only way to model that accurately would be if society's default sexism discriminated against men. In my experience, the people who shout the loudest here are already deeply of the view there is no inherent sexism against women anyway.

Comment: @halfer yes true and really it's a throw away remark, me wanting to go in and exact revenge with abuse, which would make me no better, even if it were to have an affect. I think the women who object to women like me, taking a stand for women's rights, have survived so long by aligning with the majority, and hm, seem to develop a chip on the shoulder for having survived the ordeal and don't see other women as deserving of a kind hand, if that makes sense. I think that's what you're referring to. The thing is, the vast majority of men here are amazing and supportive of women!

Comment: @MrsEd I support _people_. We are all different. If we resort to the type of discussion that puts people down based on their physical or mental properties, we are no better than the many historical examples of genocide, slavery, unequal rights, etc. I have no problem putting someone down for being an idiot, but I couldn't care less what anyone else has between their legs, what color skin they have, where they go to church, etc.

Comment: @Snowman yes, and that's the ideal way to be. I don't like seeing anybody getting a hard time for any of those reasons. Just making the comment about the women, as it was sexist, but it offends both sexes really, just as racism can offend both sides.

Comment: @MrsEd yes, in relation to societal changes that are reflected in the community here. Progress is being made!

Comment: @sbi: My post takes no position on whether the room should have been frozen. The point of linking is to show that the Lounge is no stranger to controversy. The room has shown itself to be a poor neighbor in the past. So it's probably about time we figure out some zoning regulations. Past time.

Comment: @Jon: "The room is no stranger to controversy." You day this as if it is something bad.

Comment: @Snowman: I talked about relationships and different expectations of men and women with a co-worker today during lunch in the cantina. Sex certainly was part of the discussion, as it is an integral part of relationships. Being adults, neither of us had any problem at all talking about sex that didn't apply to us. (She seems happily married, and I already have too many kids to be romantically interested in co-workers.) The difference between your water cooler and our cantina, I suspect, is an ocean. This is Berlin here, and my suspicion is you're American. Yes, IME it boils down to that.

Comment: @sbi: No, controversy has it's place. That place might even be the Lounge. Personally, I don't see a lot of benefit, however. It seems like people are choosing to be jerks just to show that they can get away with it. The internet is awash in places where being a jerk is not only allowed, but encouraged. Stack Overflow is not one of those places.

Comment: @sbi to be clear, I am not saying that everyone who participated in that chat was to blame, nor that personal topics should be off-limits in a professional environment. I have discussed similar topics at work before but in a professional way: both intent and word choice matter a lot. Also, yes I am from the USA where we are oddly both strict (nanny state culture, call the cops because a pop tart is chewed in the wrong shape) and loose (we love our guns and freedom yee-haw!) making it a bit tough to decipher our culture sometimes.

Comment: @sbi: I've had conversations about sex at work. I've also talked with co-workers about religion, parenting, politics and all sorts of controversial topics. But I also know my co-workers well enough to know which topics could be talked about constructively. It sounds like you have that same advantage in your job. But do you know how all the people in the Lounge feel about those topics? Or more to the point, if a co-worker asked you to take your conversation elsewhere, would you spend the rest of the day complaining about it? Whatever the initial conversation, the response has been childish.

Comment: @Snowman: Your answer _"I have discussed sex at work_ ___in a professional way."___ just had me sputter orange juice all over my monitor. This is a real nugget! Sadly, though, it just shows that you people really are a hopeless case. You see a nipple, and everyone falls over backwards, but guns are just fine. (This just because my news app has just popped up another alert for California.) My statement still stands, you just underlined it, but I feel too old to waste my time on discussing with this bigotry. HAND.

Comment: @Jon: _"No, controversy has it's place."_ Yeah, in _discussion_, man. Without it, there would be no discussion, after all.

Comment: @sbi: "Controversy" is not required to have a discussion. I don't know where you got that idea...

Comment: @Jon: Just to be clear: I know many Loungers in the real. Heck, I work with a Lounger. So I know the majority of the residents are a bunch of fine people – even though they might fail to pass the zelots' test on "decency". Most of them are Europeans. We talk about sex here, in the open! (Gosh! Think about this!) In Berlin, if you walk through any park in the summer, you will see nipples, and nobody thinks anything bad about it. _That_ is the spirit at work in the Lounge, and that's what gets [the meta crowd up and in arms](http://bit.ly/1YIA4Gv).

Comment: @sbi: 1.  Trying to make this about rednecks doesn't really help your case, and 2.  "fucking on the first date" doesn't remotely qualify as constructive discourse.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Inexplicably, the English Wikipedia has no entry on _"discussion"_, so I can only point you at the [German Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion). To translate the original _"Eine Diskussion ist ein Gespräch [...], in dem ein bestimmtes Thema untersucht (diskutiert) wird, wobei jede Seite ihre Argumente vorträgt."_: "A discussion is a talk examining a certain subject, where each side puts forward their arguments." Now please tell me why you would put forward arguments if not because you want to persuade the other side in a controversy?

Comment: As another indicator: [See for yourself](https://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=controversy) what German word "controversy" translates into...

Comment: @Robert: _1._ I am not trying to, believe me. _2._ Please explain, because I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @sbi: _"controversy -  noun - **prolonged** public disagreement or **heated** discussion."_ Controversy isn't required in a discussion, as discussions don't have to be _"prolonged"_ or _"heated"_.

Comment: @sbi: You might find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQFKtI6gn9Y) helpful.

Comment: @Cerbrus: So this might boil down to differences in the use of Latin words or to you using other sources (which you conveniently didn't provide).

Comment: Oh, I've just googled _"Controversy definition"_ Most of the top results agree with a form of _"heated public discussion"_

Comment: @Jon: Being born on the wrong side of the Iron Curtain, I had to wait until the 90s to be introduced to Monty Python. That, too, is, however, already long ago now, so consider me covered on this.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I just did the same: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/controversy.

Comment: @sbi: Or, you know, it might boil down to someone missing the obvious. Like the definition of respect.

Comment: @sbi: Half the definitions on there mention the discussion being more than just a calm chat without emotions involved...

Comment: @Cerbrus: And you decided for that half. _Shrug._ So it seems it is _not_ down to differences in language and culture then, but to differences in picking slightly differing definitions. Whodda thought this could be a simple misunderstanding? And what (other than he seeing you on his side, I mean, except for sehe everybody seems to strongly decide for either one here, after all) makes you think Jon had yours in mind?

Comment: If "controversy" isn't linked in some way to a _heated_ discussion, _none_ of the definitions would've hinted at that.

Comment: @Jon: I have kids, and one thing I have learned over the decades is this: You can successfully demand fear. Respect, you have to earn.

Comment: Something the lounge hasn't been too good at lately, eh @sbi?

Comment: @Seth: I dunno. I have rarely been in the Lounge in the last two years, but I still feel quite respected when I go there once in a while. Of course, that might have to do with me not smacking users on their heads because they allegedly violated rules which I cannot point out to them. People are silly that way, you know; they resent such treatment.

Comment: I don't even go to chat for the most part, but I want to say two things: (1) From my review of The Lounge I do support it being shut down.  They can create an IRC channel called "The Lounge" and go there, and have no moderators at all.  No problem, see?  (Then they'll have to pick something else to complain about, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: (2) The way I understood Jerry's comment was not actually offensive at all except in the bluntness of the wording.  My understanding of his meaning was: **"If a woman will sleep with a man without even having *gone on a date* with him, that says a lot about her character and none of it complimentary.  Such a woman is someone that *I*, at least, would prefer to avoid."**  This statement is perfectly true in my opinion and not offensive at all.

Comment: _Context is critical to interpretation. But a wise user of chat must be aware that anything they say might be seen out of context. It's doubly true of chat message that are likely to draw flags. If people misunderstand the message because it depends on context, that's your fault, not theirs._ this seems contradictory. Saying context is critical, but all things will be judged free of context, is pointless. Just say that every utterance made in chat must be made with all necessary caveats in place.

Comment: @RobGrant: Not everything will be judged context-free, but the more context that is required to "properly" understand something, the more likely it _will be judged without context_. Or, to put it another way, the more you need to do to justify something outrageous you've said, the less likely other people will excuse it. (And rightly so!) A final way to put it, sometimes context can justify something, but also reveal a deeper problem. It's been a few years, but that's exactly my recall of this event. The culture of the room was rotten.

Comment: Given in practice the global nature of this product, and the globally differing nature of outrage, I think what you're saying is in practice everything will be judged context-free, but prioritised by the norms of the mods' culture.

Answer (score 52):

I've finished analyzing this situation.

I believe you've made several errors in your assessment of the problem here:

- **Moderators are not elected to be curators.** They're elected to moderate: to mediate disputes, rein in excesses, solve intractable problems. Curators wear tiny glasses and carry light brushes; moderators wear heavy gloves and carry shovels.
- **Chat is moderated.** First and foremost by those who participate in it, with elected moderators serving as exception handlers in the manner described above.
- **Moderators generally do not enjoy moderating chat.** Heck, I suspect that *no one* **likes** moderating chat; an obligation to fulfill the duties they volunteered for is generally the only reason why a moderator would step in to do so.

The conversation you quote from came a fair bit after another moderator had stepped into the room and calmly tried to provide a bit of guidance; he was met with a fairly overwhelming response, nearly all of it negative and unproductive. My final opinion on this scene was that a handful of hot-headed room regulars took what *should* have been at most a 5-minute interaction between two or three people and turned it into a day-long circus.

I've come to believe we need three things to help avoid situations like this in the future:

1. **Clearer documentation on the fundamental nature of chat.** Disagreeing with the removal of problematic content is natural; every moderator action is a judgement call. Disagreeing with the very notion that chat *is* moderated or that chat *should be* moderated reflects a profound misunderstanding of why chat exists and *what chat **is.*** We can do better at explaining this.
2. **Better moderation guidance for room owners and moderators.** The tooling available in chat is... not well-documented. There are ways of intervening without getting mobbed; for moderators who routinely delete lengthy, unproductive discussions on the main site, it should be easily possible to rein in problems in chat without sticking their foot in the proverbial tar-baby.
3. **More deletion.** If it wasn't so rare, it wouldn't be worthy of so much note.

[I've begun a discussion on MSE with an eye toward establishing #1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat); the other two will follow at length.

Comment: "More deletion" I wonder how would that work...

Answer (score -25):

> **NOTICE** I'm waiting for mods to respond to my repeated requests for a talk.
>
> Ahead of time I'd like to deposit that

0. I think¹ this user was actually the guy who kicked up the whole thing:

   ```
   http://stackoverflow.com/users/3271844/mafagafogigante
   ```

   He's a chat user since 29th. I had literally never seen him before.
1. Not-flagging is standing policy, per request by @JonClements:²

   - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=25473493#25473493
   - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=25608655#25608655
2. I am shocked by the implication that I would "cover up" rape jokes or even condone them. I'm willing to accept that I might have failed as a room owner "moderating" there, but I will repeat my statement made [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311540/request-for-community-attention-on-a-moderators-behavior/311542#comment278407_311542):

   > This "liking rape" allegation - is it more than an urban myth? If that thing is literally true, and not a lone act of provocation or blown way out of proportion, then I'll personally vouch for deletion of the room. (Hint, I'm not buying it yet)

   I stand by that.
3. Why wasn't I contacted immediately? I know I'm one of many room owners, but Brad Larson specifically links my message to make a point. He could have consulted me. Anyone could have.

> This post is dis-satisfactory because I can't get information I need to actually know what we're looking at. I guess that'll have to wait. I understand mods are busy. But I've given this the entire evening from 20:00-4:34am and need to post this so I can sleep well.

> To be completed

---

¹ there's no way to tell until someone helps me out with the inaccessible message

² And raw a lineup for my own reference (I'm missing the message saying something like "We have an understanding") *(view source)*

Comment: For the record, sehe and I had a private discussion about today's events earlier. Moderators are always available for private chats if needed. Just raise a flag on main or, if you're an RO, invite us to a chat.

Comment: @EdCottrell Not about this. About some of the lead up. Never did this messages linked by Brad Larson enter the discussion. I'd be happy to take it offline. But right now I need to give my life priority (2 hours of sleep is already way too little)

Comment: Fair enough. Just want to avoid the false impression no one has responded to your requests for discussion.

Comment: @EdCottrell I've been raising flags to you, to Brad, to Robert Harvey, here, in comments to Brads' answer, in our existing private chat (repeatedly). Nothing worked. For hours. (I do thank you for taking the time earlier. But right now I feel the priority should have multiplied, not gone away). Tomorrow, then.

Comment: Re the "liking rape" comment: yes, it happened. You posted the very next comment. You won't be able to see the deleted comment, I don't think, so I'm linking to your immediately following comment: [**source**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27182386#27182386)

Comment: The timeline on the rape comment started [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27182381#27182381) with your comment `"I don't know where you came from, and your forced entry was a bit iffy, but you're gaining points"`, to which [mafagafogig replied](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27182384#27182384) (in the now-deleted message) `"@sehe When she likes the rape in the end."` which you then followed up with `"Sorta kinda I guess"` and then `"peeps, no flagging here. If there's an issue, we'll quietly signal the mods."`

Comment: @BradLarson The next statement is also relevant: "It'll have to be worth more than this, though"

Comment: @BradLarson thanks Brad, finally confirmation it was the new guy who posted that. Can we have a chat? (To everyone: I'm capable of seeing the transcript. Please keep the noise down)

Comment: I should note that's an entirely separate issue from what is being discussed above, but it is just one of several flagged conversations we've had to address lately. Someone had stated that they had flagged the rape comment when it happened, but the flag was quietly dismissed. It was brought back up today after this had all occurred and was dealt with them. The alleged dismissal of the flag was something that concerned me, and I read your following comment as condoning that. If I misinterpreted this, I apologize.

Comment: @BradLarson I truly think a quick chat would be the appropriate way to shed light here. I can try in the comments if you insist. If I don't hear from someone over the next 5 minutes, I'll be trying to sleep and try to do my disclosure  the comments/answer text tomorrow. It will just take heaps more of my energy. And perhaps not work. Note this private room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96739/room-for-sehe-and-ed-cottrell please feel welcome to join

Comment: The two transcript links you use in point 2 to support your argument that not flagging is some sort of official policy... don't. The first one appears to be talking about not spamming flags, and the second one is instructing to use custom flags, after handling a whole bunch. Would you like to withdraw that point?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I will not withdraw that point, as it is certainly an arrangement, that these messages do refer to. Also, the arrangement itself was clearly not made in the lounge (hence you find it ambiguous) and we've objected about that at the time. I might withdraw it if either JonClements or Mysticial says I misrepresented it. ([Making sure they see this now](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27243790#27243790)).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am sickened by this room. That rape comment and Sehe's promise to delete the room. Well please DO go ahead. It's disgusting. Absolutely disgusting. And now has been brought to the attention of hundreds of people and this will only grow. Go on. Delete the room and make a stand for decency.

Comment: @MrsEd I thought we already agreed it was the new guy who posted that comment. Also, think about this- there are over ***4.2 million*** messages in that room. 4.2 million opportunities to say disgusting and vile things, and yet 99.99% of the transcript is clean.

Comment: @MrsEd I am sad that even my (predicated) promise sickened you. I am mainly sad because I don't understand and consequently don't know what would make you less annoyed. I'm still finding the time to clear up this particular episode since I've received the missing factual information in the meantime. It will be night work again I fear. I have nothing less than decency in mind and hope I'll not be the only one that (tries to) learn from these incidents. Regards

Comment: @nick honestly that information had not been incorporated in the answer yet. Also I don't think it matters ***in principle*** that it was the new guy. I'll do you a note when I added my two cents

Comment: @sehe it doesn't matter much in practice, either.  If a sufficient number of people shout out loud enough for long enough, they will get their way whether it can be reasonably justified or not.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not that pessimistic at all. I think we have moderators that we can work with instead of antagonise (even if their actions seem to justify it; in fact resocialisatie in that case because it's not smart to potentially let yourself be played). I suggest that we exercise restraint, find a little facts and common ground. There are many things here unpleasant for all parties involved but I'm not sure that crying helps in this stage. Yet?

Comment: @sehe thank you for your reply. You can understand the liking rape comment is so offensive then? It seriously makes me feel nauseous. Maybe not everyone gets such a strong reaction, but it's really horrible.

Comment: You can see my reaction. I didn't with hold. I know what it sounds like, which is appalling. But simultaneously I was there. What reconciles the two for me (and what I think I can do better in the future) doesn't fit in these comments. Again, I'll remember to drop you guys a note once I have it written up.

Comment: @sehe just to make clear, I was not horrified by what you were saying, but what your were referring to. You do understand that yes? The thing about the room is this: many of us have nothing to do with it, unless it comes out to the public attention as it has here. So it's not like people are looking to destroy your room, but objecting to this behaviour. And my knee jerk reaction is extreme, and that's not good either, I know. It's just not what is expected on a programming site. You understand? So it's a shock. A genuine shock and outrage.

Comment: I'm gonna postpone my write up. I'm a wreck since yesterday night. It'll come.

Answer (score -45):

Perspective of a lounger that isn't particularly caught in the heat one way or another. Additionally, this is more of a general tale than addressing the particular events that triggered the current situation. And lastly, the lounge hosts multiple (overlapping) subsets of people that have different discussions and different behaviors (even different behaviors from the same person depending on the context). I'm referring to the 'meme' and 'shock' culture in the lounge below.

---

The core issue here is a mentality prevalent in the lounge compared to the moderators. The lounge attracts members with a distinct flavour of cynicism and lack of political correctness. Both are used - between lounge members - as comedic relief. Extreme sarcasm, shock, absurdities and politically incorrect humor are often employed. Then other people come in, take offense, flag, and leave, without ever taking into consideration context and/or intent.

Is this professional? No. The general language, mood and topics are distinctly not professional in the lounge, admittedly more so than other rooms. That's part of why it's a lounge - a place to unwind.

However, if the goal of SO **chat** was to provide a professional environment, I believe it has given the entirely wrong impression. To me it always has felt that SO was the professional and formal side, while SO chat was the place where you'd let loose and discuss without the shackles of formality and professionalism. *I might be entirely misguided in this impression, but the general tone in many chat rooms reinforces my belief in this.*

But I digress. The point is, when a mod comes into the lounge to enforce the political correctness and professionalism expected on the main site, it really stirs the lounge. Because it attacks it in the very reason people come to the lounge: for the humor. Most notably because in the vast majority of the cases a stranger that never has and never will contribute to the lounge comes along to take offense to something that never has and never will apply to them.

---

The views above are my own and may or may not represent the views of other loungers. Additionally, the views of other loungers often do not represent mine.

Comment: You've made the terrible mistake of using "professional" in your argument.  rip

Comment: @GregorMcGregor Except I'm not making an argument or taking a stance at all. Merely providing an explanation of why I believe things blew up. I also like that I got a downvote in under 30 seconds - a timeframe in which it's physically impossible to read my answer.

Comment: Speaking to the purpose of chat... "This site is an extension of Stack Overflow, so discussion should more or less revolve around **the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow** — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun, but **please keep it professional** and always **be respectful** of your fellow community members."  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#about

Comment: Loungers are people too.

Comment: There is a place that is safe for the kind of unprofessional cynical shock-and-awe offensive content that you speak of... reddit.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think I am going to fully stand behind Cat wanting to ban the use of "professional" in this discussion.

Comment: According to your own admission then the existance of the lounge in its current format to begin with is directly counter to the rules set for SO chatrooms.

Comment: @Magisch I thought that already was rather obvious considering the backlash.

Comment: @orlp the question then is why it was not immedeatly deleted when this became "rather obvious"

Comment: @Magisch Because simple deletion is crude and ineffective. The lounge is a collective of users consisting of over a million reputation. We're not trolls that simply need to be or can be shoo'd away. I understand that the status quo needs to be changed, and the lounge needs to move away from the unprofessional discussion (on this site), because it's not wanted here. That was not clear to me before - like others - as I've written in my answer above.

Comment: @orlp I think that a deletion and full cleaning of house is in order. In addition to finding the worst offenders and barring them from using SO chat either permanently or for a very long time. If the room then needs to be remade, it can be, with different owners that hopefully wont allow such commentary to become this commonplace.

Comment: @Magisch And I simply disagree. No further value is generated through deletion, and it will anger valuable community members. The moderators are actively working with us to keep the lounge within SO's standards from here on.

Comment: @orlp I disagree that anyone angered by the deletion of a toxic chatroom with a toxic history and owners who did nothing about it would be considered valueable or even desireable community member at all.

Answer (score -50):

This isn't really an answer--it's an extended reply to Jon Ericsson's comment claiming that my original post was misogynistic.

Short summary: this is not merely a little bit wrong, but is actually the precise *opposite* of reality.

The post in question recommended women who wanted to have at least some sort of relationship, rather than proceeding directly to having sex.

The misogynistic advice would, of course, be precisely the opposite--to go for simple "hook ups", and avoid any actual relationship.

So no, it was not even close to misogynistic--in fact, so far the opposite that I'm forced to wonder whether those who want to suppress it aren't being misogynistic (in a passive-aggressive way) themselves. That's certainly not the *only* explanation--for one obvious alternative, it's also possible they simply failed to look past their prejudices about the language used to analyze what was really being advised.

I should probably also admit that a few times I really have posted a few things that probably were misogynistic to at least some degree (in one case, perhaps even a fairly large degree). I don't claim that was a good thing, by any means, but will point out something that most regulars in the Lounge already know: my marriage has been in trouble for some time now, and I've come quite close to getting divorced a couple of times in the last year or so. Many of the Lounge denizens have acted more or less as an unofficial support group during this time.

As far as the claims that discussion of sex (or my marriage, for that matter) have no place in a professional chat room, I have to disagree about that as well. I've discussed the same (and similar) subjects with work colleagues at a number of work places (including my current one). The notion that a professional relationship precludes close friendships or truly personal discussions strikes me as utterly ludicrous.

Comment: I suspect the use of the word "fuck" in the original transcript (rather than "having sex" as your verbiage of choice) probably derails your logic.

Comment: I'm certainly glad you are able to get support from the room. Amazing communities like that are [one of the reasons I stuck around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141021/1438). I don't think you all should stop talking about important and meaningful things. I'm not at all facetious: keep doing what you are doing. My problem is that it's not at all clear what is going on to outsiders who tend to assume that the conversation is going to be focused on C++ most of the time. That and the chat items in question seemed designed to fan flames rather than help, well anyone at all.

Comment: @Jon: ___1)___ The founders, owners, and users of the room have _repeatedly_ stated, here on meta, that the room is called a _"lounge"_ for a reason. If you expect discussions about your profession, do not go into a lounge, as that is a place people hang out at to relax. ___2)___ If it is not clear to outsiders what goes on in the room, then maybe outsiders shouldn't judge what's going on the room? ___3)___ If the word "fuck" is all a moderator sees in the sentence "you want a woman who wants a a relationship, not one who just want to fuck", then maybe that moderator was a bit overworked?

Comment: ___4)___ Jerry, of all people?! Seriously?? Jerry?? That is so wrong, I don't even know where to begin. TTBOMK, I have been banned _once_. (I only learned about that time later, so there could have been other such cases.) If Jerry has been banned more than a 1000th of this, it's way too much, because he's at the very least that more reasonable and calm than I am.

Comment: @sbi _"then maybe outsiders shouldn't judge what's going on the room?"_ - Maybe, maybe not, but the room **still has to follow SO's rules / guide lines**, REGARDLESS of who created the room, don't like that? Create / join a IRC or something else. (While the last part sounds harsh and that isn't my intention, I simply don't know how to phrase it differently)

Comment: @Epodax: That there's a rule that says "no talking about sex" is brought up again and again here on meta, and turns out to not to be true each and every time.

Comment: @sbi In that regard I'd refer to hichris123 comment on the answer below,  _" ... so discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow ... "_ See [chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#about](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#about) - and in that matter, under the "Do I have to be nice?" part of the faq, there is this bit _"If you see an inappropriate, spam, or offensive chat message, please use the hover menu at the far right of each chat message to flag it"_ I would classify sex as inappropriate on a site for programming.

Comment: To address only the "this isn't misogyny" point: it becomes misogyny when men speak for women with regard to what women want.

Comment: @TylerH: My post was statement of observed fact, not speaking for anybody, any more than saying "the sky is clear today" is "speaking for the sky". And no, lest somebody try to twist that into a claim that comparing women to the sky is misogyny: still false. It's simply choosing an emotionally neutral subject of observation, to help you understand that the same process (observe and report) can be applied to almost anything, without any presumption of "speaking for" the subject of observation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: So basically you're saying that the alternative I provided was correct: they failed to look past their own prejudices about the word that was used to see what was actually being said.

Comment: @JerryCoffin When someone says "Most women want [...]", they are speaking for women. Calling it an "observed fact" is misleading; it's anecdotal... in other words, it's your opinion.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: If you want to frame it that way, sure.  For the same reasons that we say "black person" instead of using the N word.

Comment: @TylerH "it becomes misogyny" no it doesn't, that's not what that word means. And whether the thing presented is a fact, or opinion or whatever the fuck, it's not even implying anything bad so WHO CARES #disgusted

Comment: @TylerH: I've already pointed out how it's *not* speaking for anybody. The first time you made your false statement, it could be attributed to simply being mistaken. Persisting after a clear correction has been given becomes lying. Please stop that. As far as being my opinion: yes, but certainly not mine alone. Although I don't try to write every post as a research paper with full citations, multitudes of studies have reached the same conclusion for decades, so at most you can claim it [needs citation]. If it were a research paper, that would be reasonable. In chat, it's basically ridiculous.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus A more strict word is patriarchy, yes, but the term misogyny is also used to cover behavior that follows from the historical sense; hatred of women. Such behavior includes treating women as objects, discriminating against them etc. And clearly this community cares, in case you have somehow missed all the reactions to the OP to date.

Comment: @TylerH AND NONE OF THOSE THINGS ARE IN WORK HERE.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It wasn't speaking for any one person in particular, it was speaking for women as a class, which is worse.

Comment: @TylerH: You've failed to show anything here that's even similar to hatred of women, treating women as objects or discriminating against women. In fact, precisely the opposite was done and advised. If you want to address something start by addressing your failure to understand that basic fact.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If you care to do [some reading about misogyny](https://www.google.com/search?q=misogyny&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), you'll quickly see how it's misogynistic to treat women unfairly, by taking away their voice, by speaking for them as a whole, as a group, or individually, without some form of consent. The same would be true if a woman said it, though to a much lesser extent, because they have the benefit of being a part of the class of people for which they speak.

Comment: These are not mechanical rules you can apply without thinking about them jesus christ.

Comment: @TylerH: But nobody's done anything of the sort. I've never spoken for women as a whole at all. I've pointed this out repeatedly now. If you have a question, please feel free to ask about what you don't understand. You, however, must immediately cease and desist with your false and defamatory claims that I have at any time or in any way attempted to speak for women as a class. I'll remind you: you're posting publicly and on the record here, and your comments can be used as evidence against you in court. No, that's not a threat--just another statement of fact.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Nobody? "Most women want at least something of a date before they [...]" That's someone speaking for women. In the literal sense. And at **no point** have I accused you, personally, of misogyny, by the way, so you can take your thinly-veiled threat-not-threat and save it for someone else. You should make sure someone is actually slandering you before you try to intimidate them with legal buzz words.

Comment: @TylerH: Tell us how saying "the sky is clear today" is "speaking for the sky". Until you do so, your position remains one of simply spouting falsehoods, which has already been pointed out. In any case, I've also already pointed out multitudes of studies over the years, so if anything it was simply a summary of those studies. You've claimed that I spoke for women as a class, and you said that doing so constituted misogyny, so yes, you most certainly *did* accuse me of misogyny. **Stop Lying!**

Comment: @JerryCoffin Making an irrelevant analogy is called an inductive fallacy. The sky is not a person, nor is it a protected class. You've also not pointed out any studies. You've only mentioned that they exist. Trump also mentioned that he sent PIs to Hawaii to determine the truth of President Obama's birth, but that never actually happened. And no, if you read up, you'll see I've only said "someone", not "you". Please, words are important.

Comment: @TylerH: The analogy isn't irrelevant at all. It's an attempt at showing same process (reporting observations) to an emotionally neutral subject. How can you fail to grasp such a simple and obvious fact? Do I honestly need to provide specific citations of the studies? Do you question that they exist, or are you just playing silly word games to try to justify your lies here?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Considering that the conversation is about mistreatment of *people*, an analogy about speaking for an inanimate object is totally irrelevant. To address your point, saying "the sky is clear today" is in fact speaking for the sky. This is not a problem, however, because the sky cannot speak for itself, because, again, *it's not a person*.

Comment: @TylerH: First, there was never any mention of mistreating anybody. Second, no, it's not speaking for the sky. It's speaking *about* the sky. I suppose I should back off from the statement about lying though--perhaps you simply don't know English well enough to understand the real meanings of the words involved?

Comment: @JerryCoffin You're free to back from any statement you want; you've made quite a few bad ones in the past hour. I won't hold it against you if you wish to rescind any of your comments later.

Comment: @TylerH: Although I'm not surprised at this point that you fail to understand it, that was doing my best to give *you* a little wiggle room for the falsehoods you've stated here. You should take advantage of it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I've made no false statements here, but you're free to keep digging. I won't watch.

Comment: @sbi: The lounge is listed as the one and only chat room for the [c++ tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info). If I'm new to the site and I want to talk about C++, where else should I go? There's also a long tradition of naming chat rooms as specific third places (taverns, bars, etc.), but that doesn't mean you can say and do anything you like. When a moderator asks that you tone things down, that's not an invitation to get more gross. Real lounges usually have private rooms where people can be a bit more free in their conversations. Please try to be considerate.

Comment: @Jon: If there is no other room for the C++ tag, then that is a sorry state of affairs. If you want to do something about it, be my guest and make yet another attempt of initiating "A Pure C++ Room"™. If you succeeded where all others failed, I'd applaud you and be very happy about it. But the Lounge is an effort by volunteers who have no obligation at all to support C++ newbies. (And who do so nevertheless, if the questions are interesting.) There's nothing giving you the right to  press-gang them into service.

Comment: @Epodax: _" ...So discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow... "_ I'd believe in this argument the moment it's applied to the tavern. And I know quite well that I'm on the safe side there, because that will never happen. And for good reason: the chat was _created_ for the very reason to provide a place to chat relaxed, and it deliberately has the on-topic rules relaxed. Again: It was _created_ for a but if off-topic talk.

Comment: So the only question remaining is, what is "inappropriate and offensive", and what is not. Here, the religious zelots keep jumping on the Lounge whenever the topic "sex" happens to overspill into meta — _but have repeatedly failed to point or a rule that_ allows to chat about alcohol, sport, and cars, but _forbids chatting about sex._ Just as you fail to, now. And that is for good rain add well: Of course, nobody wants to be pointed at as being the one who is so backwards, they forbid talk about sex — even when their spittle forms on their lips every time this comes up. I call this bigotry.

Comment: @sbi: Calling that "Bigotry" is hardly constructive.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I see that the only thing you responded to was a trigger word. I take it you didn't know anything to answer to the arguments that made a case for the use of that word?

Comment: I'm not going to discuss arguments, where you are calling a group of users "Religious zealots" or "bigots". I find it hard to take someone seriously when that person has to resort to swearing, in a discussion.

Comment: @sbi So, on a site dedicated to programming, in a room relevant to the coding language C++  (I assume it's related to C++ because of the name of the chat room), you don't find it inappropriate to talk about sex? (Let it be known that I don't mind talking about sex, it's not a "ew" topic for me), but I would not discuss it in a public chat room dedicated to programming. At least from what I understand, the issue is not that you every now and then (read: often) or 80% of the time go off-topic, but it's the topic you decided to go to. As you point out about the other topics (cars etc etc)

Comment: May not be as strictly enforced and that, but the issue (at least from my PoV) is that those does not connect with intimacy or that kind, sex is of a more personal nature, and while **you** might not mind talking about it openly and freely, others might not, and while you could say, "Well, they can just leave then" i'd normally agree, but **since this is a programming site and chat** I'd have to say that it's fair to expect a certain filter concerning more adult material such as sex.

Comment: @Epodax: What about _"this room is a Lounge, not a C++ help forum"_ (which I have been telling here for hours, and about which I have been told repeatedly – despite contrary evidence – that it is well understood) do you fail to grasp? One last time: ___It's a lounge, not a C++ helpdesk.___ People hang out there. 3rd place, you know? And, no, I do not "find it inappropriate to talk about sex" in the Lounge. Why would I? Is it appropriate to talk about alcohol there? Sports? Engines? Animals? What makes sex so special that you guys all cringe every time it's mentioned? You are being silly.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Trigger words, again. (Some of which I haven't even used, but still you accuse me.) So my point stands, you guys _"have repeatedly failed to point or a rule that allows to chat about alcohol, sport, and cars, but forbids chatting about sex."_ Case closed then. Good night.

Comment: @sbi Not once did I say or even hint that you should become a _C++ help forum_ That was and is never my suggestion. as far as the sex thing goes, do you only read what you want to? The comment right under the one I last pinged you in is also for you, where I explain the whole sex thing. But to make it simpler the _"If you see an inappropriate, spam, or offensive chat message, please use the hover menu at the far right of each chat message to flag it"_ is decided by each mod, **is it too broad and can be interpreted multiple ways?** Maybe, but if you want it narrowed down to be more specific >

Comment: You should create a new post with that topic / feature request, bare in mind that it should be constructive and not just simply venting air. I get why you are upset / this whole thing escalated, I just disagree with the way you've approached the subject and what you are defending your "cause" with.

Comment: @Epoday: Of course, your comments saying _"on a site dedicated to programming, in a room relevant to the coding language C++ (I assume it's related to C++ because of the name of the chat room)"_ and _"this is a programming site and chat"_ can in no way at all be seen as a hint at some purpose of the room related to discussing C++ solely. What was I thinking? _Well, now that's out of the way (once more),_ ___I propose you guys just stop bringing this up.___ Thanks.

Comment: As for that "other comment": I read it and replied to it, but you keep either saying _"sex is different"_, but keep failing to point out how, or alluding to rooms staying on topic, but deny doing so. Given that denying you want the Lounge to stay on the topic of C++ was your latest turn in this cyclic game, I will just dismiss the _"but since this is a programming site and chat"_. Unfortunately, then next to nothing is left in that discussion, except for _"sex is special"_ – and thus we're back to square one. So I propose you either explain how sex is difference, or just stop wasting my time.

Comment: @sbi, right now, all the "lounge culture", word definitions and your own personal feelings about this situation really don't matter any more... Is there a next step where we should focus our attention for the common good?

Comment: @sbi You see, there is a difference between _"Being a C++ help forum"_ and _"Discussing C++"_ You seem eager to twist what ever I say into something different, as for the matter of sex, if you can't see WHY it can be seen as inappropriate to discuss it on a programming site, well, there's not much I can do then.

Comment: @brasofilo: Like actually reading messages before they're atomized, rather than just knee-jerking to trigger words? (This whole mess, if I may remind you, was started by some moderator blowing up over a message which, essentially, just said that women do not want mindless fucking, after all.) Yeah, great. __You got my attention for that.__ What do you suggest we do to prevent such a a mess in the future?

Comment: @Epoday: Look, I see three options to read your vague statements: __1)__ Chatrooms need to stay on topic. If so, point out the rule saying so, close the tavern along with probably 50% of the other rooms, and let's move on. _Otherwise, though,_ ___stop bringing this up.___ __2)__ We can talk about cars, sports, alcohol, whatnot, but not about sex. If so, point out the rule saying so, and I will tell the other Loungers to STFU abotu sex. _If there is no such rule, though_ ___stop pretending sex is different.___ __3)__ This is all bigotry.

Comment: Or to spell it out plainly: _If you constantly fail to explain what's wrong chatting about sex, despite constantly alluding to some virtual consensus saying so, maybe there is not much we can do_ ___for you?___

Comment: @sbi I get where you are coming from and what you are saying, I don't think I can explain myself well enough in this case and / or convince you in this matter, so while I do still hold a different opinion I hope you (read: the whole "mess"), comes to a proper solution. If I have given any offence know that none was meant, but most likely a poor choice of words from my side.

Comment: @sbi I believe chatrooms on SO should need to stay on topic, and I believe that a deletion of the C++ chatroom and banning of the worst offenders from chatting is in order. If a new one is created, it should be with new chatroom owners, this room is long beyond saving, imo.

Comment: @Magisch: How about you read [the arguments to this I have already made](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311540/request-for-community-attention-on-a-moderators-behavior/311557?noredirect=1#comment278940_311557) before you come and blurt out such nonsense?

Comment: @Epodax: _Look, I feel stronlgy about any discussions on equidae not being appropriate for SO. Really, if you cannot see for yourself how this is inappropriate, then I do not think I can explain this to you. I insist, though, that it is highly inappropriate._ If there's any offense in this, Epodax, then it is such illogical, irrational, and knee-jerk "arguments" coming from a programmer. This, however, is indeed rather offending. I still think bigotry is what this is all about.

Comment: @sbi I meant the whole argument we've had, none the less, I'm out.

Comment: @Epodax: I; OTOH, meant exactly these "but can't you see that sex is special?" comments which are so ubiquitous here, and which you produced, too.

Answer (score -50):

> [What's wrong about rape culture though? It's one of the most important agro industries.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22453822#22453822)

Imagine this gets flagged. You know what differentiates a regex-based profanity filter from *a moderator* when handling this case? The ability to look at the context of the message and assess whether the post at hand was actually violating guidelines, practices and common sense.

What sadly seems to be turning into a lynch mob was supposed to be a look at a moderator acting like a robo-reviewer, and when faced with such accusation, instead of approaching the matter carefully, used the powers given to him to basically come out as right and innocent in the whole situation. You have to imagine the community being given such a treatment *really* didn't like it.

That being said, since this already is a lynch mob, and "let's nuke the Lounge" seems to be a fashionable badge to be worn on your chest nowadays, I'd like to ask; if you don't think it was the moderator that was at error here, who is to blame?

Just a recap: Lounge is made of three things.

1. A room with a peculiar internal number 10, Which yes, pretty much means a very long history and tradition.
2. A set of owners with rather pristine reputation when it comes to behaving reasonably.
3. A few *dozens* of *individuals*, each with their own understanding of SO rules and policies.

It's hardly reasonable to blame #1. It's just a number. Hypothethically, any room could become (and has become) a source of content that was over the line.

I could see how you'd like to blame the room owners for that - but do think about that for a second. Room owners have asked for better moderation tools for years. Sure, the kick facility was provided after like 3 years of constant nagging, but flags, which apparently seem to be one of the ignition points here, remain a largely unsolved and often complained about subject, *even by moderators themselves*. That being said, if you remove the current set, you'd need to find a new set of people with enough C++ knowledge to moderate the C++ community chatroom across all timezones. Otherwise you'd be faced with the endless stream of "another C++ room" popping up **which was what Lounge was reenacted to prevent in the first place**.

And if you choose to blame the community, please remember, that we're not monolithic. If you want to "nuke" our community, then I fully expect you that you bring each and every person participating in the room to the "SO court" and evaluate whether a suspension is in order. Note however, that I would strongly vouch for doing this for every other member of other, even slightly controversial chatrooms; as you've said yourselves, the rules are universal for everyone.

So if you're saying "please nuke the Lounge" just because you've managed to read last *two days* out of ***five years*** of transcript because it "sounds right" to you, then please think twice about the actual execution of the idea and what it means and how unfair it sounds to all the people that stay in the room and behave reasonably, just because you've managed to cherry-pick an account that pops in and says "rape" or "fuck" as an example of the room's ongoing behaviour.

Comment: The thing about the context of your message, is that there is none. The message it is in reply to is an image that has been deleted.

Comment: @Andy I can bet that *someone* would read only the "What's wrong about rape culture" part and make a decision based solely on that. This kind of mindless evaluation is what I'm getting at. [Horse.JS Twitter account](https://twitter.com/horse_js) excels at this. While fun there, I don't think it's a proper action course for a moderator on SO.

Comment: What else should they make a decision on? You argue that context is important (it is), but then provide an example with none. The *only* thing to base an opinion on, in this case, if your linked comment.

Comment: @Andy In this case the context for the first part of the message is the latter part of it and gosh I have no idea why I have to explain it. If even such simple things are so hard to understand for people having voice here then I don't get why do they feel they have anything reasonable to say in this discussion at all.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Are you claiming that the "It's one of the most important agro industries" is the part that makes it okay? I'd been assuming that was still in the part that needed some context to make it be not horrible.

Comment: @resueman [Rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapeseed) is a crop. Pointing to agriculture [disambiguates it completely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_(disambiguation)). I don't know what other context you need.

Comment: A joke that sounds terrible *at least* unless you make a connection that most people initially won't... This is a great example of provocative, alienating, and inappropriate content that one should anticipate leading to a possible ban on a site like Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JeremyBanks the only thing I was able to extract from your comment was "I'm obsessed with trigger words". Words change their meaning basing on context. I don't think SO community is and ever was such blatantly ignorant as to disregard that and pick the most offending meaning they could find without giving any thought to what's being meant.

Comment: So, pretty much someone used a double entendre and got called out on it and rather than admitting that it was in poor taste and letting it go, you attempted to claim that they were completely innocent.

Answer (score -66):

Everything that happened and that you see in the transcript is the result of this message:

> Most women want at least something of a date before they fuck. The ones who don't, you (or certainly I, anyway) probably want to avoid.

being deleted for no reasons from moderators.

I assert that this message did not warrant mod removal, and that it was the removal that is the root cause for all of the problems that followed.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Where am I supposed to post this?

Comment: Why do you need to have this conversation on Stack Overflow, of all places?

Comment: As an edit to the question, perhaps, or -- though I don't recommend it -- as its own question.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Because it happened on Stack Overflow chat?

Comment: I think Jeremy means the conversation about what women want.

Comment: Why do you need to have this conversation on Stack Overflow chat then?

Comment: @TinyGiant What's wrong with that conversation being on Stack Overflow chat? It's a conversation like any other.

Comment: And of course, since nobody is able to answer this simple question, this "answer" is removed.

Comment: @Emrakul What? Can you express what's wrong with that message in words?

Comment: @JoshCaswell And edit to the point would put two different questions in the same "question thread". Not to mention that all existing answers wouldn't cover this aspect.

Comment: @Jefery It is a conversation inherently about sex which has no place in a  professional programming chatroom.

Comment: @TinyGiant Why?

Comment: Sex has nothing to do with programming, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: @TinyGiant Lounge C++ isn't a professional programming chatroom anyways. It's simply just "The Lounge" and it has C++ as a side topic or something like that. We're more like a social chatroom than a professional chatroom.

Comment: All chatrooms on the Stack Overflow chat network should be professional chatrooms. Some come closer to that than others, but actively trying to be the opposite of what is considered civil and professional is unacceptable.

Comment: @TinyGiant So why aren't [these](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sex&room=17) or [these](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fuck&room=6) messages also deleted? Talk about double standards.

Comment: @Jefery I'm not very fond of the JavaScript room because of that, and I don't tend to frequent the Python chat room. I do agree that both of those links point to disgusting content that should never occur in a Stack Overflow chatroom. I'm glad you agree with me.

Comment: @TinyGiant I never said I agree. I don't personally mind that content. "Sex" is not a bad word in any way. There's nothing "disgusting" about it either, so your only point for wanting Jerry's message deleted is that it's off topic. Hello? All chatrooms on SO are off topics sometimes, because believe it or not isn't populated by people whose only purpose in live is talking about programming 24/7. And everybody knows that, previous mods included and is generally well tolerated to the point that even mods come in and make jokes that have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: **Pro Tip:** *Learn how to use the SE platform properly.*  You will then be in a better position to provide informative and constructive dialogue.

Comment: I am so tempted to go into that chat room and make an equivalently insulting remark about men and then see if they want the comment removed. *sigh* fortunately we are ruled by people with well developed frontal lobes.

Comment: @MrsEd Unfortunately, they would probably enjoy that.

Comment: @TinyGiant yes you're right, I should just stick with the decent folk. thanks :)

Comment: @Jefery whats wrong with it is that SO and by extension SO chatrooms are there for programming help, and conversations such as this are a) too offensive for the site and b) blatantly off topic

Comment: @Jefery, I see both sides because I fully support the moderators in their actions, but I also understand what you were saying, which isn't offensive at all except in the bluntness of the wording.  **"If a woman will sleep with a man without even having *gone on a date* with him, that says a lot about her character and none of it complimentary.  Such a woman is someone that *I*, at least, would prefer to avoid."**  This statement is perfectly reasonable and not offensive at all. The wording was definitely the issue and *does* actually make the difference between "offensive" and "not offensive".