# A cause for self moderation and query on the events of 20 May '16

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

Early this morning, a regular in the [C# chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) posted a [crude but inoffensive message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30668856#30668856) wishing everyone a happy Friday. The message wasn't hostile to anyone, it was however flagged as offensive. Due to this a moderator came in and banned the user for one hour. This was not well met by the C# room regulars, which are generally liberal with their language. The room culture generally does not flag or punish profanity as long as it is not hostile or directed at anyone. The room owners will also generally move offensive and NSFW to the trashcan and offenders will be warned. Subsequent behavior will still be moved to the trashcan and the offender is kick-muted. I myself have posted offensive messages and been warned fairly quickly by the RO's.

The events this morning unfortunately led to a conflagration of drama. There were provocative statements from a few room regulars, however this eventually died down to users questioning the Mod's decision. The questioning generally followed the opinion "If the profanity is not intended to hurt anyone's feelings, who cares?". This led to a heated debate between several room members and the mod. The mod issued a final statement that generally amounted to "I will not tolerate rude or offensive content in this room". It was shortly after this statement that the mod locked the room. To many, it appeared that the mod locked it out of being questioned by the users, not due to vulgarity (which had by and large died down at this point).

Several room members would like clarification on why the room was locked, as well as whether moderation was based on personal preference or not. I know that in a community that is managed by autonomous and independent individuals that not all moderation decisions will always be equal, and that not all will agree with a moderators decision. To that reason the room regulars feel like it should be discussed why the room was locked. It also follows that perhaps room culture should be respected in decisions of moderation. No active chat users felt it was offensive, the present room owners argued that the language was normal for the culture of the room, no hostility was directed at another user. For this reason I also feel that room culture should be respected as long as self moderation occurs. Generally when a mod attempts to moderate without taking culture and context into consideration, his/her actions are taken as offensive themselves, and are met with a backlash. This leads to more drama and hurt feelings than the original message would have.

Comment: Just because the room's culture is more lax doesn't mean it doesn't have to conform to the general SO culture.  And even if no offense is meant doesn't mean that something isn't offensive.

Comment: I wasn't there during this, but I'd like to add that it didn't look like an argument, more of a discussion and it looked like the moderator locked the room to prevent the discussion. This can obviously be taken many ways, so here is a link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30669738#30669738

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311540/215552

Comment: The fact the the room culture allows profanity does not make it okay.  All rooms are public and anyone can lurk/be active in them.  If you post something that offends them they have the right to flag that.  From [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice): *Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.*

Comment: I'm confused.  Why does everyone keep thinking that Chat is somehow not held to the same standards as the rest of the site?

Comment: @Makoto because half of the moderators say it's not and even swear in the rooms with us, and the other half do not. We need a more specific guideline when moderating our own chat rooms. What is vulgar to you, may not be vulgar to somebody else. To some, something as simple as saying they had a shitty day is vulgar. To others, it's not. Including moderators. as we can see from their sometimes inconsistent enforcing of rules. Not their fault, they don't have specific guidelines either.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a history of people turning up in chat rooms, not liking what they read. deciding that everyone else must conform to their views and issuing flags instead of logging out:((

Comment: @SteveG: Anything that can be taken out of context to make someone feel offended would qualify as something that I'd not expect to see on the site.  Even saying "I've had a shitty day" is something I'd reserve for IRC or a very loose Slack channel.  I don't do Chat very much at all so I don't have much to base this on, but I suppose it raises yet more questions about the true purpose of Chat here on the site.

Comment: [Related] [Toward a philosophy of Chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270587)

Comment: @Makoto If that's whats decided, I'm okay with absolutely no profanity. But there are no rules or specific guidelines saying whats appropriate or whats not, only the ambiguous term *avoid vulgar language*. To make the matter worse, even the mods disagree by their actions.

Comment: @SteveG the guidance I've always heard about chat is that yes, it is more lax because people moderate it less, but it's still held to the same standards as the rest. You CAN swear on chat (just like you CAN swear on the main or meta site). You have to be okay with potentially being flagged if someone from the public sees it and flags it. (and btw, I have super thick skin when it comes to offense, so I probably would end up ruffling some feathers if I was a chat regular)

Comment: *"... when a mod attempts to moderate without taking culture and context into consideration..."* If your comments are offensive to people who don't have the culture/context, then they **are not appropriate for SO**. Most moderators, like the **vast** majority of users on the site, will not know the culture of a chat room before entering, and they shouldn't have to. Somebody seeking to talk about C# shouldn't encounter a wall of profanity, regardless of how well you think it fits the "culture" of the chat room.

Comment: @Patrice I can accept that, but I've seen moderators swear on many, many occasions in chat rooms. So which is it? No swearing at all? or *reasonable* swearing?

Comment: @SteveG Mods are users too and are also adjusting to the fact that Be Nice applies to Chat. It's safe to assume that the rules are the rules and that laxness in enforcement is temporary.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not disagreeing with you that rules are rules. I'm suggesting the current rules aren't specific enough and that needs to be addressed to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SteveG the way I've always read it is "swear if you want, but you are opening yourself to a flag, because other visitors CAN flag these". So swear if you want. But if you get flagged, you had to know it was a possibility. (then again this MAY be my personal interpretation)

Comment: @Patrice As a room owner, how am I supposed to moderate my room with those vague guidelines. I'm not speaking as a user who wants to swear, I'm speaking as a room owner with the ability to kick-mute and somewhat help moderate the room. I don't know what is right because the guidelines are vague.

Comment: If the room is that bad, why can the visitors... well... not visit, ie log out?

Comment: @Patrice Getting flagged for swearing is one thing, getting banned for swearing is another thing entirely.

Comment: @SteveG The rules are pretty specific. Where they're vague, they even say “if in doubt, just don't.” The only vagueness I'm seeing cited is that some mods don't follow them to the letter, making some people doubt that the rules are what the rules say they are.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie if there's confusion over the rules, they aren't specific enough.

Comment: @MartinJames because this site is for everyone, not just those who don't care about that group of users.

Comment: @Waterseas: A spam/offensive chat flag can only have one of two possible outcomes: 1) invalid/not sure, nothing happens 2) valid, user gets suspended. There's no middle ground here, for better or for worse.

Comment: @MartinJames That sounds like a good way to concentrate the nastiness.

Comment: If the room owners are not bothered, why should I care?

Comment: @MartinJames Because room owners have *no authority* beyond dictating the scope of their room. Nearly anyone can create a room; bam, they're a room owner.

Comment: @Waterseas Why is it a different thing? That's how it works on the main site. You get flagged enough -> you get a bigger consequence. Why should chat work differently? I don't have the full history, but if this user got enough flags and was warned, why is that an issue?

Comment: @MartinJames Because we still have the site rules and policies.  Chat is not exempt.  A lot of things get a pass but when checking if something is right or wrong we still have to abide by them.  If swearing isn't allowed on main then it is also not allowed in chat.

Comment: @SteveG see that is a very good question. I did not see it from that perspective. That..... would indeed require more guidance

Comment: @SteveG Hah, no. There will always be those who are confused about the rules. You should see my mod messages queue. :) Confusion over the rules is orthogonal to whether they're clear.

Comment: @BoltClock Exactly, the result could be "1" if swearing isn't considered offensive.

Comment: @MartinJames "If you don't like it, ignore it" is hardly an appropriate attitude for any part of Stack Overflow. This is a **moderated community**. It has a target audience of professionals and serious amateurs and the way we communicate here should reflect this. There are lots of places on the Internet which aren't moderated where you can go and behave however you'd like.

Comment: @MartinJames You're not being asked to care, mind. You're being politely asked to recognise that you don't get to decide — Stack Staff get to decide, and have. Anyone is free to refuse that request and not recognise that reality, but that probably won't lead to *positive* outcomes.

Comment: I am generally fine with mod's activity to certain vague user/message. I feel uncomfortable that the mod freeze the room to block civil disagreeing argument on his/her decision.

Comment: @tweray It's an undue burden on mods to have every mod action result in being dogpiled. If people object to moderation, contacting the Community Managers is the official means of appealing the decision. Freezing a room to put an end to objections that the mod doesn't have a couple hours to respond to is pretty reasonable, when an official appeals process is available.

Comment: That could have (and maybe should have) been handled differently @tweray... and by differently, I mean having someone else freeze the room. That's a *very* minor point here. I can't call what was happening in that room *civil* - there weren't dead, diseased cows being flung over castle walls, sure, but the room was feeding off itself. That wasn't going to go anywhere constructive.

Comment: @tweray So, if the mod is telling you "if it CAN be seen as vulgar, a flag on it means it'll get removed" What is there to "disagree" with? I,m sorry, it's a moderator telling you how the site is run.... you just go with it. Also, considering I saw a chat message from you saying "It'll only draw more attention to this room" which REALLY sounds like "we're going against the site rules AND WE KNOW IT, and we don't want to be seen".... All in all, it seems... toxic a bit.

Comment: @Undo can i please know you figured out that the discussion on that mod decision is not "civil" from what the same mod posted answer below? or you already read the transcript? fact is, it is a 50-100 messages argument, which is in quite generally civil form and really don't get anything personal imo. I would be happy to provide transcript if you prefer to judge on your own.

Comment: @tweray I've seen the transcript. Moderating real-time chat is *hard*, and it's often best for everyone to just stop talking while we pick up the pieces. There isn't a perfect solution here, but I support TheLostMind's decision here.

Comment: @Patrice i get your point, maybe the mod hold a right point here. However I should still have the right to express my argument on it as long as it is not offending to anyone. Feel free to agree or disagree on the argument, but we should allowed to speak. Freezing the room simply mute any discussion. It's like saying to SO main site user that "Hey you should never post a wrong answer! If it's wrong it should be deleted!"

Comment: @tweray you have meta to post. Which is what's happening here. You have the right to continue the argument in a nice way, like you're pointing out. You,re not entirely banned from the site? TheLostMind realised that the chat was not getting anywhere, so he locked it. And I'm sorry, but if a MODERATOR on a site where you're a userwants to completely block you from talking, they are allowed to (not saying it SHOULD happen, or it would be OKAY to, but.... it is THEIR prerogative)

Comment: @Patrice That doesn't mean that it shouldn't be changed so that's not the case going forward.

Comment: @Waterseas why should it be? This is someone going against the rules of the site, repeatedly. Now, I dunno if that particular user was banned as a first offense (if that happened, I support that it indeed shouldn't have been done this way). But if the user was already warned and STILL did it, I won't lose sleep over this.

Comment: @Patrice hold on... so... a mod can freeze a chatroom at will without guidelines or any dynamic standard? I may get a different understanding on how mod's works, but I can be wrong, so please feel free to quote or provide reference. Again, if we started to call names and spam f bombs in the room and mounting personal attack, fine, freeze the room. However if you look into the transcript, it is not happening. The mod simply disagree with us, not willing to talklonger, and then freeze the room.

Comment: @Patrice I tentatively agree with the ban, I'm not so sure I agree with the freeze.

Comment: FYI the topic of this question is simply "why was the room frozen", not "what should the power of moderators be"

Comment: @tweray so, you're aware you are a user here, and that the site is stack? There is nothing to agree or disagree. The guideline is CLEAR "BE NICE". This is "don't be vulgar to outside users". You arguing "I do not find this offensive" has no ground here. If that's the only argument that was going around, I understand why the room was frozen. Mods have better things to do than argue for hours over what "vulgar" is. By definition, if SOMEONE flagged it as vulgar, for all intents and purposes, it is vulgar. You can argue this for months, it won't change.

Comment: @Patrice Then why have a flag, let's just automate vulgarity flagging.

Comment: @Patrice problem here is not I find this offensive or not. Problem here is that I am about to say "I don't find this offensive", but I can't, because I get muted.

Comment: @tweray yeah, and in that same discussion, I can say "I love giraffes". It won't help anymore than you saying "I don't find this offensive",especially if it's been rehashed through the chat.... The mods have better things to do, so him freezing the room to stop pointless argumentation and move on to better things was appropriate.

Comment: @tweray because if right now you only argue that you should be able to speak your mind anytime, anyplace, that becomes a "freedom of speech" kinda argument. And I will quote XKCD here "if the only argument you have to defend your position is that freedom of speech defends it, this is you telling me that the only thing backing up your idea is that it isn't illegal to speak it"....

Comment: You also have the option to relocate your community off the SE chat platform, which is what happened to the [ServerFault chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) a while back, over similar... dissatisfaction with the SE network moderation and policies and such regarding chat.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I froze the room.

Let us start with the message that was posted there by a user.

> I FUC*ING LOVE C# CHAT AND I WANT ALL OF YOU TO HAVE THE BEST
> ASSKICKING FRIDAY OF THIS WHOLE CO*KSUCKING YEAR.
>
> This message wasn't hostile to anyone?

I found the words "FUC*ING" and "CO*KSUCKING" abusive so I suspended the user who posted this.

> This was not well met by the C# room regulars, which are generally
> liberal with their language. The room culture generally does not flag
> or punish profanity as long as it is not hostile or directed at
> anyone.

Yes, that's another problem with your room. You sweep many vulgar messages under the carpet. I tried to convince you that the words "cocksuck*r* was bad, you guys were of the opinion that "vulgarity is relative*, I completely agree with the *vulgarity being relative* part. Here's what mods think :

> Our standard with chat is this: if a transcript of a public chatroom
> was brought up in a public context outside of Stack Exchange, would it
> reflect very poorly on SE and its users? If so, that's something to
> act on. Rough language by itself may be dismissed even by others on
> the outside. It's what is being said that matters.
>
> Chat here is different in that it's public and is associated with the
> site as a whole. The standards for what is acceptable here are
> different than those in an IRC or Slack channel. Things said here
> reflect on the site and non-chatting users.

So, in my opinion, what was being said was vulgar. So, I had to act. Note that some words or links might seem funny to you but could be vulgar in reality. Like I tried to explain when I was in the room, some of you might consider porn as something which is acceptable on SO chat (because it is not directed at anyone), but in reality porn is unacceptable here and we have seen several instances where people have posted links to obscene videos in your chatroom.

> The room owners will also generally move offensive and NSFW to the
> trashcan and offenders will be warned

The fact that some room owners were not ready to accept that something needed to change was what led me to freezing the room. If the ROs are not happy with a mod asking them to stop being vulgar, then the room has to be dealt with.

> It also follows that perhaps room culture should be respected in
> decisions of moderation. No active chat users felt it was offensive,
> the present room owners argued that the language was normal for the
> culture of the room, no hostility was directed at another user

Again, just because it is not offensive to you doesn't mean that it isn't offensive to others.

Also note that this is not the first time I tried reasoning with the ROs about being less vulgar. If we have a room where a good number of words are as*hole, co*k, bal*s, cu*t etc, then you are probably here for the wrong reasons.

Also note that a user I suspended for posting links to obscene videos had this to say -

> **The chat is filled with vulgar content as you say**, I don't understand
> this suspension whatsoever. You could have warned me as you mention
> above, I didnt got warned about posting any "vulgar" content.

(I had warned him before).

Next, I did a search on "coc" in your chatroom and this is what I got (loads of 'em)

> - Holy avenging c*ck juggling thundercu*t of holding +5
> - You ghost that mother f*cker like he's a co*k roach.
> - co*kmongler A man who > (given opportunity) -will- suck your c*ck.

-- The list goes on

So I stand by my decision. If talking to the ROs and people doesn't help and a lot of messages are "not really offensive" to them, then the room had to be dealt with.

UPDATE:
I did have a chat with the ROs and other users about vulgarity a fortnight ago. The exact statements that I made are shown below.

- > I found that sentence offensive and deleted it. Any reasonable person
  > would agree with me. I did it after trying to understand the context
  > around it (hence didn't suspend anyone)
- > I have no plans of micromanaging this room. "To all stupid
  > people put panini in your ass****" or "I hope you like ana* because
  > you are going to get fuc**d" cannot be part of a civilised
  > conversation. Please ensure that you don't use such lines in the
  > future.
- > As long as you guys keep the vulgarity under check, there won't be a
  > problem.
- > You are one of the ROs. Try to keep it under control :). Keep it clean
  > and "less abusive". Have a great day
- > Our definitions of "rude / vulgar" are clearly different. I understand
  > that. Try to keep it as less vulgar as possible. Have a great day
  > @others

Comment: Regarding the "Here's what mods think" part, is that posted only here or is that from another Meta post somewhere? If so, could you add a link to it?

Comment: well, to be fair, you freeze the room when you are in the middle of "talking to the ROs" so there's no more talking can get held.

Comment: @Andy: They're from our private moderator chat room. These are views expressed by other moderators, quoted verbatim.

Comment: Fair enough. It sounded official and was just wondering if it was from a meta post that wasn't linked. Thanks @BoltClock.

Comment: @Andy: *Every* quotation has to be properly attributed ;)

Comment: @tweray - Well, if the ROs and other users thought that vulgarity should be allowed in their room, then there was nothing left to discuss.

Comment: @TheLostMind that's a very bold conclusion to be honest,, and you seems to be holding on it boldly too. I'd rather conclude it as "the ROs and other users have a different definition of vulgarity, and willing to discuss." The whole room is seeking some discussion and understanding on both sides idea. You seems to be only willing to judge.

Comment: again.... why should it be discussed? IF IT CAN BE SEEN AS VULGAR FROM OUTSIDE, IT IS. You can argue about your own definition of vulgar.... but that doesn't change that it can be seen as vulgar. I personally have no filter, so "c*ckmuncher" or whatever will not insult me. But I'm aware that it CAN insult others, so I wouldn't argue about "I don't find this offensive so we should be allowed to say it". If it comes down to "outside viewers can see it as insulting"... then I don't see how you would argue your point

Comment: @tweray Given this recent quote, that appears to be not true at all:

"We'll just continue as-is as we always have and someone at some point will take offense to something again and we'll repeat the whole drama again."

Seems the room is being just as stubborn, if not more so

Comment: @Waterseas the person you quote only expressed his idea, if mod disagree with it, he can simply say "no, you can't run the room that way, because of A/B/C/D". However he started to do bunch of political talking and once bored, he simply freeze the room and not allowing anyone to talk.  I don't want this to get dirty, but the mod involved here have listed a whole bunch of horrible things that he want to "protect us from" yet none of them really happened. If you wish I could quote.

Comment: @Patrice if you really read the transcript of our discussion, our main point is focusing not on "is this vulgar", but "if this is vulgar, is it too much to fire a mod ban on a single user without warning". We are mainly arguing that the ban is too strict and not a perfect activity. Again, feel free to disagree with me, and you have the right to express it. But our right to express disagreement seems to be singlehandled waived by the room freeze, all by a single mod without any general guideline or pre-warning.

Comment: @tweray It's not that the mod is "bored".  There is just no point to have a drawn out discussion in the chat room. It's not a debatable issue. Either behave and accept the rules, or you don't get to chat. If you want to discuss a moderator decision, take it to meta, which is the appropriate place for such discussions in public. Or if you wish to do so in private, use the "contact us" option.

Comment: @tweray lol, it's weird how on the question, you are arguing that you're trying to say "I don't find this vulgar", but here, you question the ban. You know, I answered to Waterseas about the ban. If that's the argument you want to have let us have that one. If the argumentation is going nowhere, then why continue wasting time on it?

Comment: @Patrice just FYI, I am not the PO. I just feel it's enough drama so I don't want to create a separate meta post just questioning the freeze. I put the ban on the specific user throwing f-bomb on a borderline. But the room freeze is something i couldn't agree with.

Comment: @tweray I am very aware that Sydney is the OP. When I said "on the question", I meant comments on the questions, where you argue all you wanted to say was that you didn't find the message vulgar. On the comments here, you are arguing that the ban is bad. It's weird how you just seem to flail around atm.

Comment: @Patrice if you really read all my comment on the question. I believe you can get my point clearly. I do oppose the ban but I can suck it. But I can't suck the fact that when we are expressing our opposition ideas we get the whole room muted.

Comment: @tweray you ever saw kindergarten children argue? They put their hands over their ears and scream until the other side caves in. This is not productive for ANYONE. Again, if your only argument is "I should be able to speak my mind" this is the poorest argument to defend your current position.

Comment: @Bart I believe there's a better way to express the necessity to move discussion to meta or somewhere else other than freeze the whole room. It is a fairly active room primarily talking/QA about c# programming. Freezing the whole room simply stopped it from doing regular functioning work. We had to just do the whole round you just described to get it unfrozen by another mod. I don't believe that's necessary,

Comment: @Patrice I am not trying to defend my position. I am simply trying to describe what has happened or what this answer didn't cover, intensively or not. I don't want to get into anything personal, but seems like you are already referencing me as kindergarten children, then I think we can drop the conversation.

Comment: You want the room @tweray? You can't handle the room!!! Ahem .. but seriously, if a mod steps in, you (the people present) have taken things to far. They are exception managers. At that point it's a matter of "understood" and you can go on. If that is not the case, they can't be asked to spend much time on convincing you. So the message needs to be made clear in another way. And that's what happened. If you want to argue the merits of the moderator stepping in, or the preventable freeze of the room, the room itself is not the place to do so.

Comment: @tweray I am labeling the argument you seem to be defending as akin to kindergarten children arguing. No reflection on you. I got into those pointless arguments at times, and I DID sound like a child(with hindsight, I see it). Sometimes backing up, re-reading the context and trying to see how you CAN change the outcome can help. Seriously, drop the pride about the room being frozen. Was the conversation REALLY going anywhere between you guys and TheLostMind? (if you tell me it WAS, I am backing up my whole position 100%. If it wasn't, then it was pointless and everyone has better things to do)

Comment: @Patrice thanks for lower the heat. Again, I am just trying to describe you the fact that we are arguing about different thing in the incident. I totally respect your point of view that mod did the right thing on banning the user saying vulgar, I may have slightly different view, but I agree to disagree. I just hope to drag the discussion to a more meaningful point rather than keep talking about "Room Culture". I am more against the mod freeze a room without warning or clear guideline at will, which imo is  a bad mod decision and fanning the problem.

Comment: @tweray but again..... your issue is the mod freezing the room because he didn't want to "listen". But if the conversation was going NOWHERE, there is no point in continuing it, no? And if there was no point in continuing, then if he just left the room out of the blue, you wouldn't have been happier, no? And just a headsup: I looked QUICKLY through the transcript, and even if you keep on saying there were no attacks or anything, I see "
When you're alone, ashamed and full of guilt, you will be ready to ascend to mod-hood." which to me is aimed at the mod, and as an attack....

Comment: @Patrice um... I'm pretty sure that's not talking about the mod, if you hover over it you can see where the conversation starts, completely not related to the incident... That's actually part of my point, the chat room is still operating and ppl still talking inside, while a big freeze hammer simply fall without any precaution and there are plenty of us don't know what exactly happened. I mean, how hard is it to say "We can't talk about this anymore, let's move this somewhere else. If we continue then I have to freeze this room"

Comment: @tweray okay then, what about "someone's power tripping"? Seriously, it doesn't look as civil as you make it sound, which really just reinforces my point.... If the conversation wasn't going anywhere, this was turning into a flame-war. From TheLostMind's edits on his answer, seems like the RO WERE warned before about what should and shouldn't happen.....

Comment: @Patrice well, if we have to cherry pick. I don't like this, please call stop if you agree. quote`If you think that using abusive and vulgar language is the only way of having fun, then you are probably here for the wrong reasons.` Just for instance this sentence by the mod is earlier, and directly suggesting that abusive and vulgar language is the *only* way for some of us to have fun. I can easily take it offensive. Since you already spend time cherry picking, how about just read the whole conversation and see if we are trying to be constructive?

Comment: @tweray wait what? I'm sorry, but that's a case of "if the hat fits...". It starts with an IF. If you think otherwise, then the rest of the sentence needs not apply. There is no offense there, as opposed to "someone's power tripping" which is VERY targeted. Honestly, I read the whole thing in the end, and my position stands. There was nothing constructive coming out of that chat. (and btw, funny how my first example didn't apply, the second one was cherry picking... seems like everything I pull you will defend without actually looking into what was said. So meh.)

Comment: With that. I'm done. Should've left that argument about 7 messages ago... but meh... I guess it's one of those times I end up arguing like a kindergartner myself.

Comment: Ohhh boy. This is what moderators have to put up with?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah… And they're wondering why they can't have nice things like rooms that don't get frozen.

Comment: There were constructive comments regarding your decision to ban the user. They were not (all) saying vulgarities were okay, some were pointing out the lack of consensus about where the line is. I was suggesting alternatives. None of this was addressed, and the room was frozen simply with "take it to meta". Other moderators after reviewing the transcript did unfreeze the room. I'm not defending the comments that spawned this, I'm questioning the decision to silence the room which was questioning your decision. The precedence is that questioning moderation comes with penalties. Dangerous slope.

Comment: @rlemon  - Questioning for clarification is different from questioning to simply make a point. I was saying that the room had crossed the line and you guys were asking me why I wasn't moving my line a to match yours. To fix something, people must first accept that there is a problem. If you keep reiterating that there is no problem, then we can reach no solution. This is exactly what happened in the C# room. You guys weren't accepting that there was a problem, so there was no point in discussing it any further.

Comment: no, *some* people were not accepting there was a problem. Like I already stated, some of us were trying to provide a alternative approach or gain more knowledge about the decision made, not to defend the comments made. Dealing with a few "bad apples" by freezing the room just escalated the situation and made those who were trying to have a proper discussion feel penalized for questioning you.

Comment: @TheLostMind If the original post was offensive then simply replacing one character with a star and leaving the original word clearly discernible is no better. Maybe you need to ban yourself... But in all seriousness it's no less offensive than the original, and ironically much more likely to be seen.

Answer (score 72):

> I'm going to be frank here, with my thoughts as a user. Everything that follows is ***my thoughts*** **as a user**, and in no way official. This isn't a stance of the moderation team or staff.

Okay, I'll bite. I'm deliberately not addressing the specific problem at hand, but rather the constant use of 'culture' as an excuse for behavior that wouldn't otherwise be tolerated.

**Room culture is a thing, but not as some rooms want it to be**. Rooms are going to have a different "culture", that's normal. Culture, in this case, means "we like cat pictures here" and "we don't like cat pictures", or "we greet everyone with a happy face" or whatever. That's fine.

What **room culture *isn't***: "we are R-rated and DON'T EVEN THINK ABOUT TOUCHING IT". I wouldn't mind if people took their R-rated conversations and language somewhere else; it doesn't need a place here. "Here" is indexed by Google, Internet Archive, and tons of other things. It's public. Do we really want this reflecting on the Stack Overflow name? Probably not.

I'm not saying that you can't use explicit language here, ever. There are some places where it's natural, and some rooms will have a *slightly* higher tolerance for it. Fine.

What is **not acceptable** is when a room gets a reputation *among moderators* of "those are the people that are abrasive to everyone and swear constantly, and if I try to do *anything* there I get pounded into the ground".

There are rooms that have that reputation, and it's not healthy.

We need to get rid of this room-culture-as-an-excuse thing. It's ridiculous and is impairing fair moderation.

Comment: What is "R-rated", by the way? R like "repulsive"?

Comment: @DanielFischer R-rated, [as in movie ratings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#MPAA_film_ratings). It's not a perfect analogy, but there isn't a perfect parallel for chat.

Comment: "Restricted". Makes sense, but I find "repulsive" would be a cooler rating ;)

Comment: "if I try to do anything there I get pounded into the ground" shouldn't it be the other way around? I mean, if moderators aren't able to argue with civility, they can just nuke the whole thing and hand out suspensions.

Comment: @Braiam Moderators are people too!

Comment: @MichaelHampton that came out of the blue...

Comment: I'd say that the users in the C# room (myself being among one of them) are some of the most willing to help amongst any of the chat rooms.  Enough people use it as a "Google this for me" service that we get annoyed sometimes, but if someone has a genuine question, we're very helpful, even to newbies.

Comment: As a C# RO and regular, I actually take offense to the way you're portraying us here. I can think of at least 3 mods that come into our room at the very least on occasion and are perfectly comfortable around us. I have never once seen you in there.

Comment: @Sippy heh, I wonder why.

Comment: @Sippy [Your account is not in the list of Room Owners](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/7)?

Comment: It was an hour ago.

Comment: @Codeman All the more reason to avoid profanity! Not all newbies with genuine questions are going to be interested in a room with this level of profanity, and hopefully you want to be welcoming to them all regardless. Being nice is part of being helpful.

Comment: It's unfortunate that a mod has to deal with all these things knowing that they will be pounded to the ground, thanks for putting up with all this with a lot of dignity.

Answer (score 56):

Full Disclosure: I am a C# RO

However, I am not pleased with what happened, and was not present during that time. My answer will perhaps naturally seem biased but it is addressing the outlook in general.

---

Profanity is essentially an instantaneous way towards having content removed anywhere on the Stack Exchange network. If you post a comment with profanity in it, and someone flags it, the system will automatically remove it without any oversight.

Chat has even less protection than comments. So if there is profanity in chat, then it is nearly guaranteed to be removed if flagged. Sometimes removal is silent, sometimes if the 10k community approves it then there is an associated 30 minute (or more depending on how many times this happens) ban from chat (not Stack Overflow). In this case, the ban length was one hour. I feel that the ban was justified. I disagree with the use of profanity in the current setting, and I feel that being banned is the risk associated with using profanity.

Arguing against the ban is therefore a losing endeavor. There is nothing to gain by arguing with a single moderator or with the moderation team as a whole, and the ensuing argument was entirely out of line.

I understand why TheLostMind felt pressured into freezing the room. It was unfortunate, and it has since been undone, but sometimes that is required during duress and there is a clear case for that here.

As a room owner, I apologize for this behavior. While I may not have been present, the outlook from us as a group has always been to be civil and it should have been upheld.

My stance in the room is as follows

> 

Just because we cannot have someone in here supporting civility at all times doesn't mean it should run rampant when there is no oversight. This is the primary reason why moderation from escalation continues to be present. [1](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30677515#30677515)

> If as a room owner you are not capable of enforcing civility in the room and coordinating with the Stack Overflow moderation team, then you should not be a room owner. [2](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/30677524/history)

And I think that the majority of the users in the room agree.

Comment: Thank you for the very sensible answer about the issue. I feel better knowing that this is the stance of at least one of the ROs.

Answer (score 43):

### Room Culture

Let's get room culture straight. **Room culture is not an excuse from the standard site policies.**

Rooms have different cultures to each other, and that's fine. Using that fact as an excuse to be offensive and scare people away from the chat is *not*. "We talk about C#; they talk about C++" is room culture; to take an extreme example, "we post kiddie porn and you can't tell us off" is not.

I'm not saying that's what happened here, but that argument needs to be clear.

### Curses! I got banned!

Cursing and swearing in chat is... touchy. In theory, the Be Nice policy applies equally in chat and on the main site: Nathan Oliver said this one well in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323484/a-cause-for-self-moderation-and-query-on-the-events-of-20-april-16#comment346475_323484).

> The fact the the room culture allows profanity does not make it okay. All rooms are public and anyone can lurk/be active in them. If you post something that offends them they have the right to flag that. From be nice: *Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.*

Moderation is generally a little more lax on this than it is on the main site. Some cursing is generally accepted; even quite a number of moderators curse on occasion. However, that doesn't take away people's right to a smooth experience and their right to not be offended. If some people find cursing offensive, *tough luck*. When curses get flagged on SE chat, I tend to edit them out, but the response really is down to the moderator.

---

I can't speak for the moderation team on SO, nor will I attempt to. However, from my perspective as a user, the discussion that was had with the moderator after the initial suspension was issued was... less than totally constructive. It's true that the nonconstructive comments died down, but there were a number of users sniping at the mod and accusing him of power abuse. As a moderator, trying to do your job to the best of your ability using the minimum "force" possible, *that's incredibly disheartening*. We're humans, we make mistakes; if you think a mistake has been made don't snipe and accuse.

My *personal* moderation response to this incident would have been slightly different. However, that's not to say that the moderator involved was *wrong*, which is why it's always important to bring these situations up directly with them.

Comment: This is all just like Lounge<C++> V2.0 :((

Comment: @MartinJames Exactly. Ideally, we can prevent that drama from happening many more times in the future.

Comment: \*low whistle\*  When you say *extreme* ...wow.

Comment: @Martin James: Isn't that what C# is?

Comment: *really? That's a thing?* @MaxVernon - Public decency laws, MPAA ratings, FCC censorship rules, explicit lyrics warnings, video game ratings, app ratings, behavior rules in any moderated gathering (on and offline), etc.

Comment: @MaxVernon As someone pointed out in comments on the Q, this is a **moderated** community. If content is offending people, it's the offensive content that's gotta go. The network's explicit policy is that the choice *should not* be to either put up with offensive content or not use the site or parts of the site. To the contrary: the choice is to either avoid posting offensive content or have site usage privileges revoked.

Comment: @MaxVernon There's always something more important; that doesn't matter. We're not going to wait for cancer to be cured and world hunger to be solved before applying the site's code of conduct policies. “There are more important things to worry about” is an inherently toothless argument.

Answer (score 10):

I know that some of this has been said in other answers, but I just wanted to add my input on the matter.

### Thoughts on the Mod's actions

So, from what I gather, the user was issued a short ban (1 hour), and the room was frozen. These actions seem in line with the site's philosophy on banning: it's a big **time-out**. It allows both sides to cool off, and recover their ability to think rationally, without having emotions clouding their judgement.

### Thoughts on "Culture"

I rarely visit chat, and I have never participated in the C# room (at all: not chatting, not starring, and not flagging). Despite that, I feel that I can explain things in a way that will be very clear.

While I respect the idea of each chat room having its own culture, that does not give permission to deviate from the expectations that are present on the normal SO site.

Chat rules are only broader in the sense that anything "too chatty" or "not constructive" on main has a home in chat. From that point, every room has a right to restrict the scope further as long as they are not violating SO's policies. There are of number of rooms that focus on programming in a certain (programming) language, while others focus on moderating SO.

### Thoughts on language

The language is unnecessary at best, and actively hostile and insulting at worst. (Except for the word "cockroach", which I do not feel warrants censorship in TheLostMind's answer.)

But I don't think that cursing is not the biggest problem; it may actually only be a symptom that some other things are present.

<sub>My opinions are mostly irrelevant in this matter, so I have substantiated everything with factual evidence. My only interest is ensuring that all parts of Stack Overflow are "nice", which is one of the core philosophies of the network. (I have no interest in chat, personally.)</sub>

I found [a research paper](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/rws_etd/document/get/ucin1321647214/inline) that I feel is particularly relevant. It presents evidence that slang language (including a number of words that seem to be used quite often in this room) are offensive to some people. But it also explored the connection between slang and sexism (its main focus), and found a number of connections.

Stack Overflow has already been the subject of [several](http://www.win.tue.nl/%7Easerebre/MSR2016.pdf) different [papers](http://bura.brunel.ac.uk/bitstream/2438/7110/2/main-6pages.pdf) that come to the conclusion that Stack Overflow has fewer female programmers, even when compared with the numbers in the industry (where there are few to begin with).

Those two papers only explored the main part of SO. As a female programmer myself, I haven't had any problems on regular SO, but I am getting very different feelings from this chat room. See:
[here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30660829#30660829),
[here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30668573#30668573),
and [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30676055#30676055).

I do not come to Stack Overflow looking for these problems; I come here for programming stuff. But I'm sure *as hell* not going to idly watch any part of Stack Overflow (or another SE site) devolve into a place where it is acceptable to marginalize the feelings and struggles of other people. And it's not just myself or my own groups that I [care about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323148).

It shouldn't be necessary to explain why things are offensive (indeed there are other reasons than the one I mentioned), nor should it be necessary to point out other examples of insensitive behaviors in this chat room that need to stop.

The defense for this behavior is:

> No active chat users felt it was offensive, the present room owners argued that the language was normal for the culture of the room, no hostility was directed at another user.
>
> If the profanity is not intended to hurt anyone's feelings, who cares?

I don't know what *was* intended, but I don't think it matters. It is very clear that the room has some [hostile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30665761#30665761) opinions, [which](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30669193#30669193) could [be](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30674895#30674895) considered [bullying](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30668065#30668065). Reference the Be Nice Policy:

> **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
> - **Bigotry of any kind**. Language likely to ***offend or alienate individuals*** or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)
> - **Inappropriate language or attention**. ***Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive***. Also, this is not a dating site.
> - **Harassment and bullying**. If you see a ***hostile interaction***, flag it. If it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page.

The three bullet points there all fall under one definition: **taboo**. While there is some degree of variance, (American culture frowns upon asking others about their salary, for example,) the concept of taboo words is understood and practiced by most, if not all, human cultures on earth. If you can write in English, you probably already know its taboos.

For good measures let me also quote parts of the moderation guide:

> you should only be flagging things that [the mods are] going to see as offensive as well

Which includes:

> Anything that [shocks the conscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocks_the_conscience) (yes, this is subjective — let your conscience be your guide.)

Note that this refers to the flagger's conscience, not the room's. And of course this applies to anything where you have the option to flag, no matter who posted it.

A good rule of thumb: if your message is something that would be flagged as "Rude or Offensive" if it was on the main site, it's inappropriate for a message in chat.

Just because there is a group of people willing to put up with the chat room's behavior does not mean that the rest of Stack Overflow should be willing to put up with it.